# Devemos aceitar questões de recomendação?

Tags: debate, big-7, escopo-do-site

As questões de recomendação costumam trazer problemas e normalmente são votadas dizendo "eu também gosto disso" ou em menor quantidade "eu não gosto disso e quero jogar essa opção para baixo".

Por outro lado, existem casos em que elas são muito bem definidas permitindo uma resposta objetiva (respostas subjetivas não são permitidas em nenhum site da rede SE) e bem verbalizadas.

Mesmo que a questão seja muito bem feita, respostas simplistas sem um bom suporte, mesmo aquelas que não se limitam a um simples link pipocam e precisam ser manipuladas pela comunidade. normalmente ou poluem o conteúdo ou colocam carga sobre os moderadores.

Essas questões podem ser aceitas? Que requisitos devem ser exigidos para que a questão permaneça aberta?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aconteceu um fato novo que eu não tinha percebido. Isso pode mudar um pouco como devemos pensar sobre as recomendações.

A SE está começando aceitar uma proposta que foi tentada diversas vezes e sempre fechada. Agora parece que vão tentar ver o que acontece com [Software Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887). Quero ver de perto como ela se comporta.

E parece que o pessoal está consciente dos problemas que podem surgir e estão tentando fazer o site ser um verdadeiro Q&A. Nem todos estão entendendo isso e pedindo que o *engine* seja modificado para atender melhor o novo site. Se o site não consegue se adaptar ao *engine*, ele é que está errado. Mas a maioria está entendendo que dá para fazer um bom site SE.

Estão, desde já, estabelecendo [regras para não virar bagunça](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13031/laying-some-ground-rules-for-software-recommendations).

E achando soluções para lidar com [respostas obsoletas](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12898/19348).

Temos que pensar nisso. Se eles conseguem fazer um site todo de recomendações, nós podemos lidar com elas qui. Dentro de determinados **critérios estritos**.

Acho que está claro que pedido de recomendação pode ser aceito quando a pessoa sabe fazê-lo. Mas muitas pessoas não sabem. Criar requisitos específicos para uma recomendação não é tarefa fácil. E não deve ser mesmo. Criar barreira de entrada dessas perguntas é algo benéfico. Proibi-las por completo, não.

Até o problema da obsolescência pode ser resolvido. Ele não é tão grave assim. A pergunta que deu origem a esta discussão realmente era problemática. Certamente o que vale hoje, não vale alguns dias depois.

Apesar das boas respostas, em [Biblioteca cliente para web services REST em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2389/biblioteca-cliente-para-web-services-rest-em-java), vimos uma pergunta ruim que pode até mesmo se tornar obsoleta em dias. O problema não é pedir por uma biblioteca, mas colocar como requisito algo efêmero.

Em algum momento a maioria das perguntas do site podem se tornar obsoletas de alguma forma. Estamos lidando com tecnologia, obsolescência é o padrão. Não vamos levar a ojeriza à recomendação tão a ferro e fogo.

Perguntas de recomendação não são *off-topic*. Mas elas podem ter todos os outros problemas que qualquer pergunta pode ter e serem fechadas por qualquer outro motivo disponível.

Longa vida às boas perguntas de recomendação!

Comment: Isto é interessante, e como mencionei na minha resposta, nesta fase "jovem" do site, perguntas de recomendação são uma mais valia. Se vão perdurar no tempo, e se no futuro vão ser aceites, tudo depende efectivamente daquilo que falaste (como está escrita e se é útil para as massas). Eu não gosto muito delas porque a tendência das respostas é serem baseadas numa opinião, e ai, como marcar/definir a resposta correta? Correta para quem? (_fica a pergunta!_)

Comment: E pedir por um serviço? [Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247691) me fez lembrar disso. Pedidos de hospedagem web grátis são bastante comuns, acho que em casos assim a comunidade seria capaz de manter uma resposta comunitária consistente. Pena que esses casos, que me parecem fáceis de resolver, sejam sobre recomendar serviços que geralmente são muito ruins...

Comment: Eu acho que essas perguntas de usuários de forma geral não funcionam, já manter conteúdo comunitário pode funcionar, mas precisa empenho da comunidade para fazer dar certo. É o que eu falei, se deixar o usuário comum fazer a pergunta não sai coisa boa. Reforço isto: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/devemos-aceitar-quest%c3%b5es-de-recomenda%c3%a7%c3%a3o/582?noredirect=1#comment355_149

Answer (score 13):

Eu acho que perguntas de recomendação podem dar certo, com moderação. O [Photo.SE](http://photo.stackexchange.com) se dá muito bem com elas, mas foi preciso definir um formato específico pra que elas dessem certo.

Os problemas que você citou são em grande parte sobre o trabalho que dá *gerenciar* essas perguntas, mas isso não se torna uma realidade até termos milhares de usuários, participando em centenas dessas perguntas.

Pro nosso caso agora, existe algum outro lugar na internet, em português, capaz de dar uma resposta melhor para *"Qual a melhor biblioteca HTTP para Python"* do que o SOPT é capaz de produzir? Nossa engine não é perfeita pra isso, mas é melhor que qualquer outro lugar em que essa pergunta pode ser feita.

Algumas das perguntas de recomendação do SO são [referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) até hoje e ajudaram uma penca de pessoas com uma lista organizada e semi-hierarquica de recomendações.

Acho que acabar com elas aqui, agora, é impedir uma série de ***ótimos*** posts de nascer (mesmo que eles acabem fechados no futuro).

Comment: Eu acho que o segredo é definir bem e aplicar esse formato. É bom saber que a equipe está aberta ao que eu sempre disse que essa plataforma deveria ser: oferecer a melhor ferramenta para se obter respostas úteis para as pessoas (desenvolvedores no nosso caso). Vejo outros sites da rede muito sectários. Claro que não se pode aceitar qualquer porcaria e tem que tomar cuidado para não afastar muitos *experts* por causa disso. Mas espero que tenhamos aqui bons profissionais que não se irritam por bobagem.

Comment: Uma das coisas que eu não tinha idéia antes de trabalhar aqui é o quanto as coisas são repensadas... Acho que essa questão do tipo de perguntas permitidas foi a discussão que mais participei desde que entrei

Comment: E a obsolescência das respostas? Mantê-las atualizadas é parte do trabalho de moderação que você menciona?

Comment: @bfavaretto Esse é um outro problema que acho que a moderação pode fazer muito, por isso precisa ter esse formato muito bem definido. O maior trabalho que vejo para a moderção é que vai precisar ficar monitorando diretamente ao através da fila de flags (sinalizações, argh!) para deletar bobagem. E sim, acho fundamental apagar listinha de ferramenta pura e simples para dar destaque para as respostas bem formuladas. Já se discutiu muito sobre isso como listinha boba (poll question) é maléfica e não torna a internet melhor. Não acho que apenas votar negativamente é suficiente, fica o ruído lá...

Comment: ... dizendo para as pessoas "é assim que funcionamos, pode fazer assim o quanto você quiser, você vai ganhar reputação por dizer que git é o maior".

Comment: @bigown definir o formato como exigindo *community wiki* não resolve o lance de gente ganhando reputação por sugerir um item popular em uma pergunta de recomendações?

Comment: @obvio171 resolveria se o pessoal fizesse isso. Ou você está recomendando que os moderadores façam isso a força em todos esses casos?

Answer (score 6):

Eu pessoalmente não gosto dessa pergunta. É impossível uma resposta autoritária, pede avaliação subjetiva, e perde a utilidade muito rápidamente (preço? isso pode mudar muito rapidamente!).

Se fosse ao menos recomendação de algo não efêmero, como uma biblioteca, ainda teria utilidade a longo prazo: a biblioteca pode ter sido abandonada, mas, presumivelmente, ainda seria possível achar a versão mencionada na resposta.

No caso mencionado do Photo.SE, não sei que tipo de recomendações fazem lá, mas, novamente, recomendações de *produtos* são duradouras, mesmo que o equipamento saia de fabricação.

Comment: Será que o datacenter onde roda um app é mais "efêmero" do que uma biblioteca que compõe a mesma?? Para pensar...

Comment: @AndréSalvati pessoalmente, não sou muito fã de nenhuma das duas, mas na minha opinião a biblioteca ainda "ganha": do mesmo jeito que ainda tem programa FORTRAN ou COBOL rodando ainda hoje - e gente dando manutenção neles - uma descrição de uma biblioteca continuaria sendo válida e útil ainda por muito tempo, mesmo que seu público-alvo se reduzisse ano após ano. Já o datacenter pode ser barato hoje, caro mês que vem, ser comprado por outra empresa depois, a qualidade do suporte cair, mudar a marca ou sair do mercado. Tudo que se escrevesse sobre ele agora teria de ser reavaliado depois.

Comment: Em outras palavras, não é o datacenter que é efêmero, **as informações sobre ele** é que são...

Comment: A essência dessa comunidade é mostrar as opções para quem tem dúvidas e foi essa a intenção quando coloquei a pergunta "Quais as opções para hospedagem de apps em Java?". Enumerar e citar características de um serviço/framework/produto é muito diferente de RECOMENDAR o mesmo. Aliás, já vi isso inúmeras vezes no SO inglês. É isso mesmo o que vcs querem? Um SO em português mais restrivo (e chato) do que o original?? Se for assim, realmente é um mau começo...

Answer (score 6):

Pessoalmente não me dou muito bem com questões de recomendação, é tudo um jogo de opiniões que tendem a "expirar" rapidamente.

É extremamente difícil que os diversos utilizadores envolvidos concordem que determinada resposta está correta, pois os factos são muito corroborados por uma opinião pessoal e/ou fatores com um limite de tempo.

Em termos de longevidade da validade ou utilidade da resposta, a mesma não vai perdurar no tempo devido às inúmeras variáveis com a qual a mesma foi colocada e aceite.

O que é hoje não é amanhã e num site deste género, é estar a colocar e responder perguntas "hoje" para as fechar "amanhã".

## Mas

Concordo inteiramente com o final da resposta que o Gabe♦ colocou, o site é muito jovem e acima de tudo precisa de ganhar reputação e utilizadores através de bom conteúdo!

Para já, concordo que perguntas de recomendação podem-se revelar uma mais valia e devem ser aceites, partindo sempre do principio que o seu conteúdo vai caia na categoria de "bom".

Comment: Sua posição ficou clara para o amanhã. Mas qual sua posição para usar hoje? É a mesma? Podemos aceitar boas perguntas de recomendação nesse começo, ou já devem ser fechadas?

Comment: @bigown Alterei o final da resposta, estava demasiado filosófico e pouco conciso :) Em suma, concordo que neste momento perguntas de recomendação podem-se revelar uma mais valia e devem ser aceites.

Answer (score 5):

Já utilizei de muitas questões de recomendação, para escolhas que precisei fazer de frameworks, padrões e etc.
Acredito que questões de recomendação podem ser muito significativas, porém, como praticamente qualquer outra, podem ser mal formuladas e/ou ter respostas que não trazem fatos e uma contribuição real para a questão.

Mais do que discutir sobre questões de recomendação, a maneira como esta foi feita, a preocupação com elucidá-la, isso sim deve ser acompanhado.

Por fim, acredito que o requisito básico para uma questão ser aceita é sua objetividade e clareza. 
Perguntas curtas, com pouca informação para ser usada como referência aos que responderem, geralmente são passíveis de ambiguidade. No mínimo, perguntas ambíguas devem ser editadas (preferencialmente pelo autor) para melhorar seu conteúdo.