# O que fazer com perguntas que pedem recursos externos?

Tags: debate, perguntas, big-7, escopo-do-site

Pegando o exemplo [Como exportar uma página HTML/C#(Razor) que contem elementos SVG para PDF?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2384/como-exportar-uma-pagina-html-crazor-que-contem-elementos-svg-para-pdf) que pede por recursos externos (até houve uma edição para não ser links, o que dá na mesma).

O bfavaretto até colocou uma resposta que ficou interessante, não caiu na armadilha do *link-only* que pessoas menos experientes provavelmente fariam. Mas ele excluiu por achar que ela não respondia a pergunta.

Outro exemplo: [Biblioteca cliente para web services REST em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2389/biblioteca-cliente-para-web-services-rest-em-java)

Já é um caso de recomendação, que não deixa de ser um recurso externo, mas pelo menos a pergunta conseguiu informações relevantes para o site. Só teve um caso de *link-only* que infelizmente recebeu votos.

A discussão sobre o problema da recomendação está em [Devemos aceitar questões de recomendação?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/devemos-aceitar-questoes-de-recomendacao).

Mas ela ainda sofre do problema de pedir essencialmente recursos externos, apesar da maioria das respostas não se limitarem a isso. Mérito dos autores das respostas. A pergunta não ajudou.

É a típica pergunta não muito bem aceita no SO (mas tem muitos casos por lá também). Em outros sites menores da rede é algo bem mais aceito.

É o tipo de pergunta que faz parte do nosso escopo?

Podemos aceitá-la dando algum tratamento específico?

Qual é a linha que separa uma boa pergunta pedindo recursos externos e uma ruim?

Pedir que o recurso externo tenha, obrigatoriamente, notas e comentários sobre o recurso com informação relevante, ajuda a pergunta ser aceitável?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vou comentar alguns exemplos.

**[Como exportar uma página HTML/C#(Razor) que contem elementos SVG para PDF?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2384/como-exportar-uma-pagina-html-crazor-que-contem-elementos-svg-para-pdf)**

Neste momento o principal problema da pergunta é não ser clara. Ela pede "dica de componente para ajudar nesse trabalho" e "qualquer código de exemplo ou alguma referência externa". Porém, como faltam mais detalhes na pergunta (que pedi ao autor em um comentário), fica difícil dar qualquer tipo de resposta, incluindo recomendações (fundamentadas). Se as informações que faltam forem acrescentadas, acho que é possível responder com informações relevantes, de maneira objetiva.

**[Biblioteca cliente para web services REST em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2389/biblioteca-cliente-para-web-services-rest-em-java)**

Pede recomendação de biblioteca, e inicialmente me desagradou bastante. Mas as respostas postadas, especialmente a do Anthony Accioly, mostram que essa pergunta tem uma chance no site. Se daqui a um tempo as respostas se tornarem desatualizadas, há a chance de os autores, ou outros usuários, atualizarem o conteúdo. Também há a chance de isso não ocorrer – e provavelmente isso vai acontecer com a maioria das perguntas desse tipo se tivermos muitas no site. Mas acredito que essa decisão não precise ser tomada agora.

Esta outra pergunta também pede recomendação, e está fechada como "principalmente baseada em opiniões":

**[Material em português para iniciantes em programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349/material-em-portugues-para-iniciantes-absolutos-em-programacao)**

Ela pede recomendação de livros e outros materiais para iniciantes. Isso é bastante amplo, e dá muita margem para  respostas opinativas. Como comentei na pergunta, acho que esse tipo de pergunta só funciona se houver uma única resposta do tipo community wiki, onde vários usuários colaborariam numa lista única. Acho impossível isso acontecer no atual estágio do site, talvez mais adiante.

Outra que merece comentários:

**[Binding do Facebook SDK 3.6 para Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2240/binding-do-facebook-sdk-3-6-para-android)**

A pergunta original somente pedia a indicação de um recurso externo ("Alguém sabe onde posso encontrar o Binding do Facebook SDK para Android na versão 3.6?"). Eu editei a pergunta incluindo "Como adaptar o que encontrei para o SDK mais novo? Existe alguma outra alternativa?", com base na resposta que ela já tinha quando foi fechada. A resposta mostra 3 caminhos para resolver o problema, e nenhum deles é uma simples recomendação de onde encontrar o tal recurso.

#### Conclusão

Acredito que essas perguntas tenham seu lugar no site neste momento, contanto que não tenham outros problemas sérios (de clareza, amplitude ou outros). Em geral, se a pergunta é capaz de receber uma resposta que seja completa (de maneira alguma [somente um link!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links)), que tenha um conteúdo relevante, ela tem condições de permanecer. Algumas podem precisar de edição para chegar nesse estágio. Para podermos julgar esse tipo de pergunta, por enquanto é preciso que elas "assentem" um pouco no site, por isso peço [calma antes de votarem para fechar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/537/quanto-tempo-esperar-antes-de-votar-para-fechar-um-pergunta).

Um porém: ainda não estou 100% confiante de que perguntas assim funcionarão bem no site no futuro, especialmente pelo volume delas que o site poderá receber quando estiver aberto. Se for decidido que elas ficam, é possível que no futuro precisemos reavaliar a decisão.

Comment: Concordo com os quatro exemplos. Não gosto muito de respostas agregadoras, mesmo usando uma CW, mas não estamos tendo problemas com isso no momento. Podemos deixar para decidir cortar mais pra frente se for problema. O que vale é a qualidade do conteúdo. Temos que analisar o conteúdo que pode ser gerado, sem preconceito obtido no SO. Devemos lembrar que somos mais amplos que o SO. Não podemos aceitar tudo, mas podemos pelo menos tentar receber o que [agrega ao camarote](http://vejasp.abril.com.br/blogs/pop/2013/11/04/rei-do-camarote-vira-meme-e-ganha-gifs-animados-e-montagens-na-internet/) :)

Comment: Concordo. Estava faltando o termo "conteúdo" na minha resposta, fiz uma pequena edição para incluir. Mas se o "rei do camarote" aparecer por aqui, sou a favor de bani-lo :)

Answer (score 2):

Eu fui uma das pessoas que respondeu a pergunta [Biblioteca cliente para web services REST em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2389/biblioteca-cliente-para-web-services-rest-em-java). Dei um jeito de demonstrar um pequeno exemplo retirado de uma biblioteca específica + uma lista de links sobre demais bibliotecas com uma pequena descrição (e, quando cabível, links para a documentação específica que atendia aos requisitos do autor).

Vou então tentar me restringir à essa combinação de pergunta + respostas e cavar a opinião "genérica" através de casos concretos. (Ainda bem que "me restringi", se não isso seria uma dissertação de mestrado)

**Sobre a pergunta:** Enquanto ela com certeza dispara certos alarmes (por demonstrar falta de pesquisa, ser ampla demais e até um pouco subjetiva) acredito que seja valida pelo principal critério do que deve existir no Stack Overflow: "Conteúdo útil para programadores".

**Justificativa:** Tratando-se do SO em Inglês, não sei quantas vezes joguei no Google algo como "*Library W vs X*", "*Best Tool for Y*", "*Fastest library for Z*". Consultas altamente subjetivas, mas que estão sempre na minha lista pessoal de curiosidades na hora de tomar uma decisão. Na maioria das vezes encontrei perguntas do SO (muitas vezes fechadas por serem subjetivas) porém elas geralmente me dão informações úteis e links para documentações, comparações e *benchmarks* <s>escondidos</s> difíceis de achar quando você não domina o assunto. Outro ponto é que essas perguntas que pedem recomendações, indo contra todos os princípios da comunidade, geralmente tem um número altíssimo de visualizações e votos. No mínimo, sempre encontro informações sobre 2 ou 3 bibliotecas altamente populares e cheias de "fãs" no SO em inglês (parece que um "fã" tem que votar pela sua biblioteca favorita quando encontra uma pergunta dessas). Ou seja, tanto por experiência própria quando por estatística, essas perguntas se mostram úteis.

---

**Sobre as respostas somente com links:** Aqui minha opinião já é um pouco diferente. Acho que esse tipo de resposta deve ser aceita apenas na condição de que:

1. Não exista nenhuma resposta melhor.
2. O autor ainda está trabalhando na resposta dele (o que não parece ser o caso da resposta específica a qual você se referiu).

**Minha opinião:** Eu removeria a resposta *link-only* dessa pergunta em específico por não se enquadrar nem em 1 nem em 2.

**Justificativa:** Nesse caso o pfugazza postou depois do utluiz, e o utluiz já de cara tomou cuidado não só de selecionar a biblioteca de referência para resolver o problema quanto de postar um pequeno exemplo demonstrando como utilizar a API. Mas vamos imaginar por um segundo que esse não fosse o caso, que o pfugazza fosse o primeiro a responder. Vamos considerar o fato do primeiro link da resposta do pfugazza não resolver o problema do autor. Também vamos considerar o fato do segundo link da resposta estar com com a URL errada (acabei de editar). Mesmo assim, a resposta ainda aponta para a biblioteca "mais popular" conforme a opinião do autor (que, apesar de não vir ao caso, realmente representa a implementação de referência da [JSR 399](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339), e, logo, é tremendamente popular).

Agora digamos que eu seja o autor da pergunta ou um usuário externo qualquer que encontrou essa resposta no Google (lembrando que estamos assumindo que nenhuma outra resposta existe). Partindo do pressuposto que eu não conhecesse o Jersey, minha primeira tentativa seria jogar *Jersey Client API* no Google e lá encontraria a resposta para meu problema.

A resposta "agrega valor"? **Sim**.

Agora digamos que o utluiz tenha repondido na sequência. Várias horas se passaram desde a resposta inicial do autor, logo, ele não demonstrou nenhuma iniciativa em melhorar a resposta dele. A resposta do utluiz claramente supera a do autor: Além do exemplo, possui um link funcional e relevante para o capítulo correto da documentação que resolve o problema do autor.

A resposta original "agrega valor" agora que a resposta do utluiz existe? Na minha opinião **Não**.

Eu respondi algum tempo depois (tendo tomado cuidado de não me referir especificamente ao Jersey) com um exemplo concreto que utiliza outra biblioteca popular, além de mencionar várias alternativas que, ao meu ver, merecem ser investigadas.

- A minha resposta "agrega valor"? **Sim**
- A resposta do utluiz continua "agregando valor"? **Sim**
- A resposta original do pfugazza "agrega valor"? **Não**

Tenho consciência que esse "padrão de qualidade" baseado em respostas que sobrepujam outras (falei bonito agora) é difícil de implementar; que se algum dia for implementado teremos que tomar cuidado para criar critérios objetivos; e que esse tipo de raciocínio abre precedentes para "corridas pela primeira resposta" (o que nunca foi um problema para mim, quanto mais rápida a resposta melhor, desde que o autor não se esqueça de melhorá-la). Mas, problemas a parte, as melhores comunidades que conheço possuem alguma regra de *trumping*. E acho que, apesar de concordar que para o volume da SO regras absolutas são mais fáceis de administrar, temos todas as ferramentas disponíveis para administrar o site com outro tipos de regra se assim a comunidade decidir.

Ok, estou inspirado demais para o Meta hoje (é o problema de passar a semana escrevendo documentação hehehe). Câmbio e desligo.

P.S.: O amigo bigown cometeu um erro ao começar essa história de Rei do Camarote no Meta. Prevejo uma variação de [OMG Ponies!!! (Aka Humanity: Epic Fail)](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) sendo redigida em breve.