# O nível de detalhamento de uma pergunta de utilidade publica e não conceitual é motivo para fecha-la?

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq

> *Esta discussão deve ajudar ou evitar que certos tipos de perguntas explicitamente sejam impedidas nas regras, ou liberá-las. Da forma como as regras estão, pelo que consigo compreender, aparentemente são permitidas.*

Tomem como base a **pergunta problemática [Script para apagar backups antigos, baseado em padrão do nome do arquivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6040/script-para-apagar-backups-antigos-baseado-em-padrao-do-nome-do-arquivo)**. Esta pergunta gerou dúvidas quanto a estar dentro das regras atuais ou não.

Agora exemplos não problemáticos

1. [Como calcular o determinante de uma matriz em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5127/como-calcular-o-determinante-de-uma-matriz-em-javascript)
2. [Como buscar um endereço por CEP nos Correios?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400/como-buscar-um-endereco-por-cep-nos-correios)
3. [Qual o melhor jeito de fazer um sistema de login em senha com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-o-melhor-jeito-de-fazer-um-sistema-de-login-em-senha-com-php)
4. [Como realizar uma requisição Ajax com Javascript puro (sem APIs)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3167/como-realizar-uma-requisicao-ajax-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis)
5. [Função para incrementar valor dentro da div](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6000/funcao-para-incrementar-valor-dentro-da-div)

Os dois pontos a serem abordados são

> - **A pergunta problemática deveria ser fechada?**
> - **Se a pergunta problemática deveria ser fechada, que regras fechariam ela sem implicar fechar também questões como os exemplos até então permitidos**?

Importante ressaltar que, ou há uma mudança de regras ou o fechamento de questões como essa serão sempre subjetivos. O único ponto que vi de principal diferença desta questão para outras não conceituais é que ela tem mais detalhes.

---

### Contra-argumentação para o não fechamento da pergunta problemática com as regras atuais

1. Ela não é duplicada de outra
2. Ela não é descontextualizada. (comentários a seguir)
3. Está claro o que está sendo perguntado. É até mais detalhada que as outras
4. Ela não é ampla demais. Ela é mais detalhada (comentários a seguir)
5. Não é baseada em opiniões pessoais, nem é subjetiva

**Descontextualizada**

1. Ela é on-topic. [Em Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic) em especial **Desenvolvimento de scripts para servidores CRON**, entre outros da mesma lista.
2. Ela não se encaixa no tipo *não pergunte*. [Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar de fazer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

**Ampla**

1. Ela não tem muitas soluções possíveis. É fácil saber que uma resposta poderia ser aceita
2. A resposta é, sim, mais longa do que perguntas diretas e pontuais, porém é factível com até menos código do que outras questões. Um shell script muito provavelmente ficaria abaixo de 100 linhas. Logo é complicado afirmar que essa pergunta seria fechada sem implicar que qualquer questão que envolva código e não seja resolvida em 50 linhas deveria ser fechada

**Comentários adicionais**

Essa questão em específico, não tem um contexto de uso pequeno. Boa parte dos desenvolvedores, que são publico alvo do SOPT, poderiam passar por uma situação aonde uma solução para uma questão como essa seria útil, logo é **complicado afirmar coisas como "é um projeto pessoal**" ou de "pouca utilidade se resolvido". **Não é complexo ou longo o suficiente para ser classificado como "um projeto completo inteiro"**.

Comment: Eu dei a minha opinião na outra questão que o @mgibsonbr abriu porque acho que a dificuldade é justamente sobre a especificidade do problema. Mas adianto aqui que eu só não concordo com o seu contra-argumento do item 4: muito embora a sua questão esteja de fato muito bem detalhada, ela é sim bastante ampla porque trata de vários assuntos (ou "requisitos", como preferirem).

Answer (score 4):

Abri uma [outra pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/886/215) aqui no meta para tratar especificamente da categoria de pergunta na qual eu creio que a sua se encaixa: "Perguntas que pedem por código sem um problema específico em mente". Dá uma olhada lá, e veja o que acha. Comentando então sobre a diferença entre sua pergunta e as "não problemáticas":

1. [Como calcular o determinante de uma matriz em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5127/como-calcular-o-determinante-de-uma-matriz-em-javascript)

   Na minha opinião, ambas as perguntas são equivalentes. Não há motivo pra uma ter `+8` e a outra `-4`. Sem entrar no mérito se são perguntas desejáveis ou não, on-topic ou não, digo apenas que ambas deveriam receber o mesmo tratamento.
2. [Como buscar um endereço por CEP nos Correios?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400/como-buscar-um-endereco-por-cep-nos-correios)

   Essa seria uma pergunta que [busca por um recurso externo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/577/215). Ou no mínimo como interagir com um sistema externo. Se sua pergunta estivesse igualmente  buscando por uma ferramenta de automatização de backups (mais precisamente, limpar backups antigos) que atendesse a tais e tais requisitos, ela se enquadraria nessa categoria.
3. [Qual o melhor jeito de fazer um sistema de login em senha com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-o-melhor-jeito-de-fazer-um-sistema-de-login-em-senha-com-php)

   Isso é uma pergunta mais conceitual do que de implementação. Ok, a solução está restrita à linguagem PHP, mas o foco da questão é **o que fazer** e não **como fazer**, i.e.: dentro das capacidades dessa plataforma, qual a forma que garante mais segurança. No seu caso, parece que você já tem a estratégia de solução bem traçada, falta só implementá-la. Se sua pergunta fosse sobre achar uma boa estratégia, estaria no mesmo patamar (você *abriu espaço* pra estratégias distintas, mas o foco da pergunta era implementar algo completo a partir de um requisito pré-estabelecido).
4. [Como realizar uma requisição Ajax com Javascript puro (sem APIs)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3167/como-realizar-uma-requisicao-ajax-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis)

   A pergunta aí é sobre quais recursos os browsers oferecem (qualquer um / *cross-browser*) para se fazer algo, que bibliotecas estão disponíveis, como usá-las. Se sua pergunta fosse sobre como usar os recursos de cron, ou manipuação de arquivos, etc, seria semelhante.
5. [Função para incrementar valor dentro da div](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6000/funcao-para-incrementar-valor-dentro-da-div)

   Nesse caso há um código pronto, e o OP quer ajuda para depurá-lo. Essa pergunta é distinta o suficiente das demais, creio que uma comparação não faz nem sentido.

Quanto à sua contra-argumentação, concordo, sua pergunta não se encaixa nos critérios existentes. Vamos ver com a pergunta nova que acabei de abrir, o que a comunidade acha, se vale a pena explicitar uma nova regra (seja de permissão ou de proibição).

Por fim, quanto ao seu comentário:

> ... é complicado afirmar coisas como "é um projeto pessoal" ou de "pouca utilidade se resolvido". Não é complexo ou longo o suficiente para ser classificado como "um projeto completo inteiro".

Eu te pergunto: uma resposta que estivesse correta em todos os sentidos (i.e. plataforma de escolha, mesma estratégia, etc) mas que usasse uma convenção **totalmente diferente** para os nomes dos arquivos daquela que você propôs, seria aceita?

Creio que esse é um caso onde a maior especificidade atrapalhou sua pergunta, e deu-lhe a aparência de uma situação "faça pra mim meu trabalho" (ainda que o propósito não fosse esse). Esses detalhes finais não acrescentam em nada à pergunta, e a tornam "mais localizada" (i.e. menos útil a terceiros). Mesmo o argumento "outros poderiam se beneficiar, se usassem o mesmo padrão de nomenclatura que eu" é fácilmente derrubado pelo contra-argumento "minha resposta atende à sua pergunta, se *você* usar o mesmo padrão que eu"...

Minha sugestão é procurar pelo **núcleo** da pergunta, o que está sendo buscado e que se satisfeito - ainda que todo o resto esteja errado - responderia a pergunta. E retirar toda especificidade adicional que não tem nada a ver com esse núcleo encontrado. Você pode manter certa especificidade como **contexto** (i.e. *eu* estou fazendo asssim), mas deixando uma separação clara do que é contexto e o que é pergunta. Ou seja: o que é responsabilidade *minha* fazer, e o que se espera de quem vai responder à pergunta.

Comment: Para "mas que usasse uma convenção totalmente diferente para os nomes dos arquivos daquela que você propôs, seria aceita?" é sim. A questão relata um problema, e sugere uma abordagem para solução. Se olhar para esse contexto, o que a diferencia da maioria das questões do tipo "estou tentando desse jeito aqui" é que ela é mais detalhada desde a primeira vez que é escrita. Não tem regra específica que impede essa pergunta ali, embora as pessoas possam ficar aplicando -1 por gosto pessoal.