# Perguntas que pedem por código sem um problema específico em mente

Tags: debate, perguntas, escopo-do-site

Algumas perguntas apresentam um código e pedem por ajuda para finalizá-lo/depurá-lo. Outras têm um problema específico e [não sabem como expressá-lo em código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/105/215) (ou pela sintaxe, ou pelas bibliotecas, etc). Outras [buscam por recursos externos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/577/215). Mas tem algumas perguntas que simplesmente dizem "tenho o requisito X, como implementá-lo?". Exemplo:

- [Como calcular o determinante de uma matriz em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5127/como-calcular-o-determinante-de-uma-matriz-em-javascript)
- [Script para apagar backups antigos, baseado em padrão do nome do arquivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6040/script-para-apagar-backups-antigos-baseado-em-padrao-do-nome-do-arquivo)

Do meu ponto de vista, as perguntas são equivalentes (i.e. apresentam um problema potencialmente de utilidade pública, não têm dúvidas sobre a parte conceitual/algoritmo, e pedem uma implementação em determinado ambiente/com determinados requisitos). Entretanto, uma recebeu `+8` votos, a outra `-4`. Nenhuma delas foi proposta para fechamento.

Na minha opinião, esse tipo de pergunta é muito semelhante a pedir um recurso externo, exceto que no caso o que se pede é que se **produza** um recurso "externo" como resposta (tipo um *crowdsourcing*) - e um que se enquadre perfeitamente nos requisitos do OP. E na minha concepção, uma resposta válida para uma pergunta dessas seria indistinguível de, por exemplo, copiar-se um recurso externo e colar-se como resposta (no caso do determinante da matriz, por exemplo, é o que foi feito na resposta aceita).

Esse tipo de pergunta deve estar no foco do site? É inegável que, se o problema for comum o bastante, uma resposta pode ser útil a muita gente (da mesma forma que a indicação de um recurso externo também pode). Por outro lado, isso descaracteriza um pouco o site: em vez de perguntas e respostas, temos requisitos e implementações. Além do quê fica a questão de *quem* julga o que é relevante para um público maior e o que só interessa ao OP, onde se traça essa linha?

Comment: Só um comentário geral: _Perguntas que pedem por código sem um problema específico em mente_ não significa perguntas inúteis. Ela podem ser justamente o contrário: uma pergunta que sumariza uma quantidade grande de problemas em uma só pergunta bem elaborada mais ainda assim com escopo não amplo demais a ponto de não poder ser respondida. Isso não é _muito diferente_ de, por exemplo, perguntar como inverter uma string em javascript. É uma pergunta também sem um problema específico **mas que poderia ser usada para problemas específicos**

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Com certeza não são [necessariamente] inúteis, inclusive expus isso no último parágrafo acima. Mas elas são sim diferentes de perguntas no estilo ["como fazer X"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105/215) no sentido que estas buscam por uma biblioteca já pronta e/ou exbarram em problemas originados na linguagem/plataforma, enquanto o tipo de pergunta sendo debatida não possui essas características (daí o "sem um problema específico em mente").

Comment: Quanto à "quantidade grande de problemas (...) com escopo não amplo demais", sem problemas, mas na minha opinião funcionaria melhor no formato ["buscar recursos externos"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/577/215). Quem quisesse responder com código próprio ainda poderia, mas o foco da pergunta estaria bem definido. No formato que está, receio concordar com o critério de fechamento adotado: "não está claro o que está perguntando" (e após uma leitura cuidadosa, discordo que essa pergunta é "ampla demais"). Vou sugerir uma edição na sua pergunta, se não concordar basta revertê-la depois, ok?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eu acho a [resposta do @LuizVieira](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/896/12) absolutamente correta, e acredito que ela tenha explicado muito bem o que se passou na cabeça da comunidade, mas infelizmente a discussão persiste. Sendo assim, aqui vai minha tentativa de dizer a mesma coisa, de outro jeito, para talvez tornar tudo ainda mais claro.

## Eu tenho um problema...

O Stack Overflow existe para resolver problemas. É uma ferramenta muito poderosa, que pode te desatolar num momento de desespero... basta você dizer *qual o seu problema!*

Mas o que é um problema? O aquecimento global é um problema.
Sentar no sofá e o controle remoto estar a 1 metro de distância também é um problema.

Ambos são problemas mas resolvê-los requer esforços totalmente diferentes. Isso porque eles são completamente diferentes sob qualquer ótica não-generalizada. Infelizmente o Stack Overflow não serve para resolver nenhum dos dois, mas essa diferença de escopo de um problema também pode ocorrer aqui.

Algum tempo atrás, no MSOEN, @jmac [deu uma definição interessante](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/175506), usando uma analogia com quebra-cabeças:

> Se a pergunta define o ponto de partida e o ponto de chegada, mas pede peças demais, ela é **ampla demais**.
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A pergunta sobre backup se encaixa nessa categoria. Não é o caso para a pergunta sobre determinantes... Não há um subproblema de programação envolvido, ela só pergunta como calcular um determinante em Javascript. A resposta pode ser a implementação do algoritmo, ou a referência a uma função já existente no JS e desconhecida pelo autor, ou a indicação de uma biblioteca de matemática para o JS que tem um método para calcular `det`.

## O que está dando errado?

A pergunta de backup apresenta um conjunto de regras que precisam ser satisfeitas, mas nunca diz **o que está dando errado**. Por que o autor não está conseguindo implementar? Qual a dificuldade que ele está encontrando? Em suma, **qual é o problema?**

Onde as coisas estão dando errado?

- Você não sabe calcular a diferença entre datas?
- Não consegue ler o conteúdo de um diretório?
- Está tendo problemas para copiar arquivos de um lugar para o outro?
- Não sabe criar novas pastas?
- Não sabe como executar comandos de terminal de dentro do programa?

Escrever um script de backup como o pedido envolve resolver *diversos* problemas menores que seriam muito mais úteis no site se expostos separadamente. São as diversas peças do quebra-cabeça que você está pedindo.

Ao postar o problema macro, e ignorar os problemas micro, acaba-se prestando um desserviço à comunidade, mantendo a solução para vários problemas comuns dentro de uma pergunta em que eles não recebem o destaque que merecem.

## Pequenos problemas, grandes perguntas

Problemas existem nos mais diversos tamanhos, e o Stack Overflow funciona muito bem para muitos deles. Sempre que você tiver algo grande pela frente, tente encontrar os pequenos problemas que compõem o seu grande problema. Dessa forma todos podem entender o que está acontecendo, e dar respostas que vão ajudar a você e outras milhares de pessoas!

---

### Adendo

Eu fechei a pergunta de backup novamente como **Ampla demais**, porque essa é a categoria em que ela se encaixa. Mas algumas boas edições foram feitas desde que escrevi esse post e talvez agora ela possa ser reaberta.

Cabe à comunidade decidir:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6040/12

Comment: Boa resposta. A única coisa que tenho opinião diferente é a questão ela já é uma subdivisão de um problema maior e difícil de ser ainda mais subdividida. A questão debatida pode ser **considerada complexa**, mas a resposta não é ampla como outras que exigem bem mais explicação ou mesmo tem muitas soluções possíveis.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Tudo bem que ela já seja uma subdivisão, a questão é que ela pode ser ainda mais subdividida. Uma pergunta simples pode ter uma resposta complexa e ainda assim tratar de um único problema, que tinha ramificações que o autor não sabia. A pergunta de backup é, desde o começo, sabidamente complexa e composta de várias partes distintas.

Answer (score 5):

Eu já acho que as perguntas que você exemplificou são semelhantes no sentido de que solicitam código, mas *não são equivalentes*. Sua diferença está em um ponto que eu julgo fundamental nessa discussão, e que tem tudo a ver com o título da sua questão: a especificidade do problema.

A pergunta "Como calcular o determinante de uma matriz em javascript?" apresenta um problema/assunto pequeno, que poderia ser enxergado como "concentrado em um só requisito". Se existisse uma função que faz isso em Javascript, a resposta seria bastante direta e objetiva, e a pergunta talvez não se caracterizaria como um pedido de código (aliás, alguém que usa outras linguagens/ferramentas, como Matlab ou R, por exemplo, poderia já estar acostumado com a existência de tal tipo de função). Como não é o caso do js, a solução é propor um script ou indicar uma biblioteca que faça o que foi pedido.

A pergunta "Script para apagar backups antigos, baseado em padrão do nome do arquivo" já apresenta uma quantidade maior de pequenos problemas/assuntos, entre eles:

- Propósito e estratégias de backup
- Agendamento de tarefas
- Listagem de arquivos em disco
- Diferenças de implementação entre linguagens
- Portabilidade de código

Cada um desses assuntos poderia gerar uma questão independente, que também poderia (ou não) solicitar código nos mesmos moldes da questão sobre o determinante, mesmo que fossem utilizados "requisitos" mais ou menos localizados (o meu ponto aqui é que não importa muito se a nomeclatura dos arquivos é X ou Y).

Mas o fato é que essa pergunta tem muitos assuntos e por isso uma solução (boa ou não) precisa necessariamente envolver a todos. [Na outra pergunta colocada aqui no Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/885/o-nivel-de-detalhamento-de-uma-pergunta-de-utilidade-publica-e-nao-conceitual-e) sobre essa mesma questão, eu concordo com quase todos os itens da contra-argumentação do OP, exceto com o item 4 ("Ela não é ampla demais. Ela é mais detalhada"). Se os assuntos que eu entendi e listei acima como constantes da questão não são suficientes pra indicar que ela é realmente ampla, pode-se observar esse trecho da sua resposta:

> Eu te pergunto: uma resposta que estivesse correta em todos os
>   sentidos (i.e. plataforma de escolha, mesma estratégia, etc) mas que
>   usasse uma convenção totalmente diferente para os nomes dos arquivos
>   daquela que você propôs, seria aceita?

Note que isso pode acontecer também lá na questão sobre o determinante: outras pessoas podem postar respostas com sugestões alternativas de implementação. Mas, as variações são muito menores devido ao escopo menor da questão.

Em resumo, muito embora ambas as questões acabem por solicitar código, pra mim parece claro que há essa distinção de especificidade: a primeira é mais pontual, e até mesmo simples de ser respondida; a segunda é mais complexa, e requer soluções igualmente complexas. Talvez por isso ocorra essa diferenciação nos votos. É muito mais fácil responder à primeira pergunta do que à segunda, e isso talvez motive mais os respondentes. Por outro lado, um pedido de script que pareça "muito complexo" pode levar a entender erroneamente que se trata de preguiça para fazer a lição de casa.

Eu sou da opinião de que não há nada de errado em solicitar ajuda com uma revisão de código ou em receber em resposta código que ajuda em um determinado problema. Problemas pontuais tem realmente muito mais chance de serem uteis a outros utilizadores e interessantes pra quem está lendo, e soluções para eles são material bacana de termos por aqui. Mas não acho pragmático mantermos questões como a segunda exemplificada. Em minha opinião o conteúdo é importante, mas deveria ser dividido em questões menores como, por exemplo, "Como apagar os últimos X arquivos, dado que sua nomeclatura é YYYYY?", "Por que essa estratégia XXX de backup é boa?" ou "Como agendar a execução do backup via código?".

Comment: Concordo com suas colocações (em maior parte - não estou muito certo se o problema da segunda questão é mesmo só por ser ampla, ou tem algo mais), mas gostaria de frisar que o que está em discussão não é o autor ter demonstrado esforço ou não, mas sim esse tipo de pergunta estar ou não no foco do site. Pois se alguém hipoteticamente faz uma pergunta "pedindo código", e **ele próprio responde** [imediatamente], isso claramente não seria uma situação de "faça meu trabalho pra mim", mas ainda seria necessário critérios para determinar se essa pergunta é ou não bem vinda no site.

Comment: Sim, com toda a certeza a discussão não é sobre esforço. Eu tentei justamente me afastar da discussão sobre "lição de casa". Tem algo no meu texto que ficou confuso nesse aspecto?

Comment: Não, fora o fato de que esse ponto é citado diversas vezes durante a resposta. Mas pra mim ficou bem claro sua posição sobre cada uma das perguntas, não houve qualquer confusão.

Comment: Eu citei bastante porque pra mim parece ser essa a motivação geral da galera que ofereceu downvotes na segunda questão. Mas, acho que você tem razão. Vou editar pra remover. Não ajuda no contexto da discussão.

Comment: Concordo plenamente com o que diferencia as duas perguntas. Não vejo a pergunta sobre determinante como boa, mas concordo que o problema que ela apresenta é mais comum, útil e tem uma resposta simples de ser dada, o que não vejo na pergunta sobre backup. É uma distinção importante de se ter para entender porque uma foi aceita e a outra rejeitada.

Answer (score 3):

Compartilho seu ponto de vista: encaro as perguntas como equivalentes e considero ambas de baixa qualidade.

Eu, particularmente, sou contra ambos os tipos de perguntas. Elas demonstram pouco esforço do OP na tentativa de resolver o problema. O foco do site deve ser mais "estou com este problema, me ajudem a resolver" e menos "tenho este problema, resolva para mim".

Claro, pode ser que eu esteja "contaminado" pela experiência no SO, mas acredito que seja uma boa forma de guiar a comunidade.

Answer (score 0):

Vou separar em dois pontos distintos a serem avaliados aqui

1. **Uma pergunta ser contra as regras**
2. **Uma pessoa não gostar da pergunta**

Em ambos os casos, o único motivo que pode levar uma pergunta a ser fechada, é o 1, ser contra as regras. O motivo 2, de carater pessoal, não pode levar a encerrar uma pergunta simplesmente porque ele é subjetivo. O máximo que as pessoas podem fazer, e já fazem, é dar -1, que é um recurso que já existe.

Então vem a pergunta: porque essas duas questões foram avaliadas diferentes porém somente uma delas foi fechada? Bem, pelo critério 2. Gosto pessoal.

Outro ponto que o Gabe comentou é que, na opinião dele, o que diferencia as duas perguntas é que uma é de utilidade publica e a outra não. Pergunto: é possível afirmar isso? **É possível afirmar que desenvolvedores estão mais interessados em um código que calcule o determinante de uma matriz, uma pergunta típicamente acadêmica, do que desenvolvedores que façam backup?** Novamente, é subjetivo. Uma questão pode parecer menos útil do que outras, mas se isso for usado como argumento, teriamos que fechar uma quantidade muito, mas muito grande de questões do SOPT porque foram consideradas como não pertinentes.

### Numa situação como esta, só há duas alternativas

1. **Mudar as regras, adicionar mais um tópico do tipo "Esta questão é lição de casa e não está nas nossas regras"**
2. **Não mudar nada, e apenas manter que quem não gosta da questão apenas dê -1, como sempre foi**

Notem que ao optar por mudar as regras, isso vai implicar fechar uma quantidade significativa de questões cuja solução envolva código e não seja única e exclusivamente revisão de código ou copiar e colar uma solução que já exista pronta na Internet.

De qualquer forma, conforme até explicado em [O nível de detalhamento de uma pergunta de utilidade publica e não conceitual é motivo para fecha-la](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/885/o-nivel-de-detalhamento-de-uma-pergunta-de-utilidade-publica-e-nao-conceitual-e), conforme a FAQ e até mesmo os temas on-topic, não é possível fechar essa questão sem alterar as regras, e a justificativa específica que foi posta para fecha-la nesse momento é até mais absurda, por ser exatamente o oposto do que a questão está:

> colocada em suspenso como **não é claro o que você está perguntado** por ramaral, Math, Erlon Charles, Gabriel Gartz, Rodrigo Deodoro ontem

Ter sido fechada por esse motivo só mostra que não regra específica para o que chamaram de "lição de casa" (o que é até engraçado, pois determinante de matriz é bem mais lição de escola do que backup) fez usuários que não tem muita ideia do que está acontecendo fechar por um motivo aleatório qualquer.

### Comentários adicionais

O motivo que mais se assemelha para fechar ela é

> **amplo demais**
>
> Ou há muitas respostas possíveis ou boas respostas seriam muito longas para este formato. Acrescente detalhes para reduzir o conjunto de respostas ou isole uma questão que possa ser respondida em poucos parágrafos.

Dividindo o amplo demais nos dois grupos:

1. **Não existem tantas respostas possíveis assim. Essa regra é usada quando a pergunta é muito vaga. Essa pergunta ali, novamente, é mais específica que o comum**
2. **Ela também não tem uma resposta longa. É até mais objetiva que outras questões**

Novamente, se não for adicionar uma regra ao estilo "esta questão é tarefa de casa", outra possibilidade seria adicionar uma nova regra do tipo "esta pergunta é específica demais".

Adicionar critério "pergunta específica demais" também traria efeitos colaterais.

Aliás, até mesmo reprimir o que o @mgibsonbr chamou de resposta crowdsourcing, soaria até estranho em um contexto que existem respostas do tipo wiki da comunidade.

Reforço: não estou querendo desestabilizar o SOPT nem desafiar as pessoas aqui. Apenas estou questionando que as regras atuais não só não impedem como até mesmo endorsam esse tipo de questão detalhada, e que se não forem mudadas as regras, não há como fechar esse tipo de questão ali senão por *eu não gosto da pergunta, mas não sei porque exatamente não gosto*.

Comment: Eu concordo com o Luiz Vieira, a sua pergunta do backup ficaria melhor como várias perguntas separadas. Se eu fosse fechar, fecharia como "ampla demais".

Comment: Somente uma foi fechada **justamente** porque foram avaliadas como sendo diferentes, e como disse no meu comentário eu concordo com a visão diferente sobre elas. Talvez uma boa forma de analisar as perguntas seja tentar entender como subdividir a questão. A pergunta de matrizes tem um cerne bem definido: "Como implementar essa função matemática" enquanto a de backup é uma *junção de problemas diferentes*, que apresentam cernes diferentes e por isso mereceriam estar em perguntas distintas.

Comment: Na verdade, se olhar a de backup ela só envolve ler arquivos de um diretório, analisar o nome, e apagar arquivos de um diretório. Fechar uma questão por esse motivo de manipular arquivos de um diretório de sistema operacional fecharia uma quantidade bem grande de questões. Só relembrando definição de amplo: **Ou há muitas respostas possíveis ou boas respostas seriam muito longas para este formato**. Não existem muitas respostas possíveis, nem a resposta é longa.

Comment: Emerson, existem claras divergências de entendimento sobre a pertinência da pergunta, mas eu realmente não acho que ela foi fechada meramente por gosto pessoal. Você diz que a sua pergunta não é ampla porque as respostas não são longas, mas os fatos são que (1) ela não teve respostas sequer razoáveis até o momento e (2) ela foi fechada como "não clara" muito provavelmente porque há muitos requisitos. Não seria simplesmente mais fácil você dividir o conteúdo em mais perguntas?

Comment: Aliás, comparando essa questão com uma sua outra (veja, não estou querendo pegar no seu pé, apenas discutir essa abordagem de pergunta, ok?): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4940/javascript-nodejs-setinterval-com-inicio-programado-estilo-cron-simples Mesmo com a gratificação as respostas demoraram, e a resposta aceita - embora de qualidade técnica garantida pela sua apreciação - tem qualidade discutível para a comunidade porque não acompanha explicações mais detalhadas (praticamente tem apenas o código com alguns comentários). O ponto é que problemas mais atômicos têm respostas sucintas.

Comment: @LuizVieira a pergunta foi feita ontem. Fechar uma pergunta porque não teve resposta imediata? Em qualquer site da SE ou fóruns de TI em geral **não é considerado como válido impedir um tipo de pergunta porque respostas não são imediatas**.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Não foi isso que eu disse. Eu só estava contra-argumentando que ela é ampla. Mesmo depois de toda a visibilidade (ainda que seja ruim), ela não teve respostas. Foi isso que eu quis dizer.