# Como podemos lidar com as "listas"?

Tags: debate

Nós temos um caso como [Material em Português para Iniciantes Absolutos em Programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349/material-em-portugues-para-iniciantes-absolutos-em-programacao), que eu acredito ser um ótimo recurso que nossa comunidade é plenamente capaz de criar e gerenciar. Material de programação em Português é escasso, e nem sempre de qualidade, e um conjunto de pessoas experientes dando conselhos sobre o que pode ser útil para um iniciante é algo que nenhum outro site em língua portuguesa é capaz de gerar.

O "listas" está entre aspas porque esse tipo de pergunta costuma ser mal vista em qualquer site do Stack Exchange. Então, pra evitar preconceito, eu vou chamá-las de ***"Construção Colaborativa de Conteúdo"***, ou ***3C***, pra não ter que digitar aquilo tudo.

O problema é que essas "listas" são acusadas de diversas coisas:

- Subjetivas demais
- Baseadas em opinião
- Impossíveis de se manter
- Muito específicas

Esse nem sempre é o caso. Uma pergunta clássica como a [The Definitive C++ Book Guide (O Guia Definitivo de livros de C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) mostra que é possível obter um outro resultado, com os especialistas colaborando para criar um recurso valioso à comunidade. Melhorando-a ao invés de piorá-la.

O passado justifica o receio com esse tipo de questão, mas também demonstra o valor que uma lista bem mantida tem para a comunidade. Como fazer para incentivar a criação e manutenção de conteúdos colaborativos, evitando cair nos maus hábitos?

Comment: +1 porque esta é uma discussão que precisamos ter, e por tê-la trazido ao meta. Mas não sei se concordo com a sua opinião.

Comment: Gabe, na sua pergunta existe algum factor Google? ie, se a possível indexação de conteudos de tais _listas_ é um factor a considerar na motivação da sua opinião e que possa ser boa para o SOpt, para além da discussão central que lançou?

Comment: @Sergio Qualquer conteúdo que é bom para os usuários *atuais* e *futuros* é bom para o SOPT. Uma pergunta de "lista" pode ser útil à comunidade, e isso é o suficiente pra sucitar o debate

Comment: Esta é pra você, Gabe: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5248/

Comment: @bfavaretto Não é pra mim, é pra comunidade. Eu acredito que uma pergunta assim **pode** receber um conjunto de respostas boas. A questão é como incentivar essas respostas, e a manutenção delas

Comment: Foi uma brincadeira, Gabe... Claro que todo conteúdo é para a comunidade. E para deixar claro: sou absolutamente a favor de bons conteúdos, contanto que se encontre uma maneira de permiti-los que não dê margem ao surgimento de grandes volumes de ruído.

Comment: Apareceu hoje no metão: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223776/are-list-questions-appropriate-on-stackexchange

Comment: Dear lord, não tinha visto esta q&a nunca... é gigante! Lendo assim por alto pensei que talvez pudessemos discutir mecanismos de exposição das wiki de tags (leitura pros novatos + manutenção pros veteranos).

Comment: @brasofilo Não discordo de você... Provavelmente seria a melhor solução

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depois de ponderar, discutir, ler as sugestões, não-sugestões e opiniões sobre o assunto, nós (eu e o Shog) chegamos num formato que acreditamos que valha a pena tentar.

## Uma Modesta Proposta

O valor de uma pergunta como essa em pauta é **indiscutível**. A comunidade de programação precisa ser receptiva aos novos usuários, e trabalhar sempre para diminuir as barreiras de aprendizagem da nossa área.

Um site com a relevância do Stack Overflow, em qualquer língua, e que atrai tantos programadores talentosos consegue, sem sombra de dúvida, manter uma excelente lista de recursos (livros, tutoriais, wikis, etc) onde um iniciante possa aprender sobre uma linguagem ou um desenvolvedor experiente possa aperfeiçoar suas habilidades.

Por outro lado, como foi bem colocado aqui, nós enfrentamos dois desafios ao fazer isso:

1. Uma resposta contendo uma grande lista de livros é difícil de manter epode rapidamente cair no esquecimento e defasar. Não se encaixa bem no nosso modelo.
2. Nós realmente temos um bom lugar para agregar o tipo específico de material que essa pergunta pede, os `tag-wikis`. Seria melhor utilizá-lo.

São dois pontos muito relevantes e que precisam ser levados em consideração. Ao mesmo tempo, os `tag-wikis` são partes "invisíveis" do SOPT. Os usuários mais antigos sabem que ele existe, mas nunca vão lá. E os novatos, justamente os maiores beneficiados pelo `tag-wiki`, não sabem que ele existe. Isso não é bom.

As pessoas, novatos e experientes, **precisam** ir ao `tag-wiki`. É uma ótima ferramenta para transmitir conhecimento e garantir que várias pessoas tenham acesso a um conteúdo de qualidade. Então porque não juntar os dois mundos?

### O melhor de dois mundos

Eu passei alguns dias pesquisando bons livros de programação em português para as 5 maiores tags do site e adicionando-os em seus respectivos `tag-wikis`. Depois de montar essas listas, eu editei a [primeira resposta da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/404/12) com links para cada uma dessas tags, falando sobre a existência dos `tag-wikis`.

É uma alternativa que eu acredito que pode ter sucesso. A pergunta não precisa ficar sob constante vigilância contra defasagem, já que manter o `tag-wiki` atualizado é do interesse da própria comunidade em torno das tags e, ao atualizá-lo, a resposta é melhorada ao mesmo tempo!

Nós podemos ter mutirões anuais de atualização das listas, para garantir que os livros continuam bons e relevantes, os links não quebraram, etc. Seria muito bom para o site, estimulando a constante atualização e reciclagem de todos.

### Nem tudo é perfeito

Obviamente esse não é um plano sem falhas... As principais que eu vejo:

- Não sei onde por bons livros sobre *programação* mas que não envolvam uma linuagem específica, alguns podem se encaixar em [algoritimo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritimo), [estrutura-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/estrutura-de-dados), etc, mas não sei se isso seria o melhor.
- Também não sei o que fazer com os *cursos* (como o Codecademy). No momento eles estão na resposta, mas talvez seja prudente encontrar um lugar melhor.
- Obviamente a lista que está lá não é completa. Foi resultado de bastante pesquisa, mas não posso atestar a qualidade de tudo que está lá.
- O que fazer com as outras respostas?
- Esse modelo, obviamente, não pode ser aplicado a toda e qualquer pergunta de lista no site. Não foi criado com o intuito de resolver de vez esse problema, mas sim de melhorar uma pergunta específica.

### *Post mortem*

A pergunta foi **reaberta**. Ela tem um excelente potencial e não há dúvidas de que pode ser útil para milhares de pessoas. Espero que todos colaborem para termos `tag-wikis` cada vez melhores.

Comment: Regarding the other answers... I think it is wise to re-use a model that we've tried a few times on Stack Overflow: lock the question such that only one (wiki) answer can be edited, converting the other answers to edits in the appropriate places. I've added the lock for now, and converted the answers to comments - y'all can repurpose them as you see fit.

Answer (score 17):

Começo dizendo que vou colocar a minha opinião. Ninguém é obrigado a concordar com ela.

O que for decidido aqui, eu seguirei. Todos devem seguir. Ninguém pode agir conforme seu gosto. Nos máximo alguém pode se abster em casos que não goste de algo, mas não pode agir contra a vontade da comunidade. A decisão que sairá daqui será o que a comunidade decidir ou a SE impor. Eu acho que a empresa pode impor o que ela quer para o site. É um direito dela. Desde que ela coloque de forma clara, transparente e oficialmente, teremos que acatar. Eu entendi até agora que será uma decisão da comunidade. E se for isso, então a empresa terá que acatar o que decidirmos. Então todos devem pensar bem o que vão decidir.

### Introdução

Não importa como chame as listas, elas são listas. Elas não se encaixam no mecanismo do site. Nós temos aqui um site de Q&A e não podemos esquecer disso. Não podemos desvirtuar isso.

Quando eu criei a proposta do site eu sempre pensei que ele seria um site mais inclusivo. Para quem não sabe, a proposta era chamada inicialmente de "Software Development" para deixar claro que deveríamos ser mais inclusivos. Sempre achei que deveríamos aceitar qualquer assunto que envolvesse diretamente o **desenvolvedor fazendo seu trabalho**. Mas nunca foi intenção adicionar tópicos que poderiam interessar ao desenvolvedor apenas tangencialmente ou mudar o mecanismo dos sites SE. O Area 51 deixa isso claro. Ou o processo do Area 51 não deve ser levado em conta? Lembro que o site nunca teve a intenção de ser "Tudo sobre TI".

Antes de continuar, quero deixar claro que não tenho nenhum privilégio adicional por ter criado a proposta. Se a comunidade quiser desvirtuar totalmente a proposta original do site, ok. Eu posso não ficar feliz, mas é um direito da comunidade. Ainda bem que não parece ser o caso. Com diferenças aqui ou ali, há mais ou menos um consenso entre a comunidade que devemos ser inclusivos sem exageros.

### Minha visão

O que eu vejo e a imensa maioria das pessoas ativas da comunidade (se não forem todas) **não** estão querendo que o nosso site seja um monstrengo do SE. Vejo a preocupação de seguir o **mecanismo de Q&A muito bem sucedido em todos os outros sites da rede**. Não vejo apoio em fazer um experimento aqui para aceitar o que não é aceito em nenhum outro site da rede. Nem mesmo os sites mais novos.

De fato, me parece estranho o discurso de mudar o mecanismo. Eu até gostei dessa discussão porque ela parece ser necessária e estava faltando um posicionamento oficial nesta e diversas outras questões. Ainda assim acho que o debate principal deveria ser o que é on-topic no nosso site.

Não acho que deveria existir discussão se devemos mudar o mecanismo de Q&A que fez o SE ser o que é. Não adianta nós acharmos que vamos ter conteúdo melhor que em outros lugares se vamos fazer exatamente o que os outros lugares erram. Aí seremos mais um. Não criei a proposta de site para ser mais um site em português com recursos ruins. Criei para **ser mais um site SE 2.0**. Nem mais, nem menos. E repito que estou colocando a minha opinião, você pode apoiar isto ou não. E ressalto que eu entendo que esta discussão está sendo necessária.

### O problema das listas

Listas atraem muitos "me too". Listas favorecem respostas "link-only". Listas deveriam ser fechadas porque elas sempre são baseadas em opiniões, porque elas são muito amplas, até mesmo são muito localizadas na maioria dos casos (o que seria off-topic hoje) e há casos em que existem até outros problemas.

Listas não são perguntas, listas não produzem respostas, **listas não se encaixam em um site de Q&A**. Nós somos um site de Q&A e o conteúdo colaborativo é criado em cima de respostas com diversidade de conteúdo aqui e não listas de itens. Itens que ficam defasados, que são muito difíceis para dizer qual é correto, separar o que é opinião, o que ajuda de verdade e o que é ruído. Todos os **problemas que as pessoas vêem nas listas são reais e vivenciados por quem tem experiência na rede**. Esse problemas não são invenções que nunca deveriam ter acontecido na rede.

Um problema inventado foi a separação do SO em subsites para tratar de coisas que algumas pessoas não gostavam. E porque dá para saber que é uma invenção? Porque quase tudo o que tem nesses sites filhotes do SO continuam existindo no SO e em alguns casos até em quantidade maior que no site filhote. Mas de qualquer forma era um problema de tópicos.

Já disse e repito que devemos reproduzir os sucessos dos outros sites, em especial o SO. Devemos evitar seus erros. Excluir listas não foi um erro. Foi uma solução para um site de Q&A. Não queremos deixar de ser um site de Q&A.

Todos os exemplos que vemos de listas são ruins. Todos! É possível haver algum bom? Claro que é. Mas *eu* nunca vi.

Aqui só tiveram exemplos ruins. Concordo com o bfavaretto que não temos comunidade suficiente para mantermos listas organizadas. Mas mesmo que tivéssemos, teríamos que subverter o mecanismo. Teríamos que ficar proibindo as pessoas de fazer o que elas costumam fazer, ter moderação ativa. E não acho que o benefício vale o esforço de um *possível* resultado bom. Curiosamente o exemplo que ele deu para uma lista que deu certo, não é uma lista. Em nenhuma momento foi intenção ser uma lista, foi um pedido de recomendação razoavelmente bom.

### O que fazer com as listas

Então não podemos ter listas de recursos para os iniciantes? Podemos sim. Temos local para isso. São as **tag wikis**. Já disse antes. Se uma comunidade consegue se organizar para manter de fato bom conteúdo em forma de listas, então essa comunidade será mais do que bem-vinda para manter isso nas tag wikis. É lá que esse conteúdo deve estar.

Listas precisam ser discutidas. Nós devemos permitir discussão no site? A solução que deram para uma pergunta foi discutir no chat. É uma forma. Mas ainda é muito estranho uma pergunta ter que ser discutida. Eu particularmente acho que a discussão necessária deveria se dar no meta e não no chat. **Tag wiki + meta é uma combinação excelente para listas**.

Já disse e repito que sou contra exceções. O SO criou uma exceção porque houve pressão da comunidade para ter. Aqui está ocorrendo o contrário. E criar uma exceção é mais um erro que o SO fez, na minha opinião. Sempre vão surgir inúmeras discussões do porque uma coisa é permitida e outra não. Sempre alguém vai pegar a exceção para querer criar uma regra.

Se a comunidade achar que deve ser uma exceção para o raro caso de ter pessoas suficientemente comprometidas com sua manutenção, eu não vou me opor, mas não vejo porque precisa ter essa exceção quando temos outra **solução muito mais adequada**.

### Exemplo de lista que não deveria existir como pergunta

Eu vejo a lista de livros do C++ como um exemplo do que **não** se deve fazer, do que foi feito errado por pressão da comunidade. E não foi tão bem aceita assim pela comunidade. Ela criou muito desgaste.

E até paralelamente eu diria que se alguém quiser ter uma lista de livros de C++ aqui eu diria que ela não é uma lista, é apenas uma resposta linkando para a pergunta no SO. Afinal este site não foi criado para eliminar totalmente a necessidade de inglês para desenvolvedores. Conforme já discutido em uma comunidade brasileira muito forte no assunto, fora daqui, todos os livros de C++ em português (traduções ou nacionais) são terríveis. Quem quiser aprender C++, procure um livro em inglês. Isso vale mais ou menos para qualquer livro de computação. Vai ver o Head First em português e dê muita risada.

A lista de sites de aprendizado de programação usada como exemplo tem sugestões bem ruins. E aí, vamos resolver como as respostas ruins? Ficar ativamente excluindo elas? Vamos ter que ficar discutindo, justificando, melindrando o autor? Gastar reputação para negativar algo que nem queríamos que estivesse ali?

Eu acho que listas raramente podem ser feitas com qualidade, mas listas sem qualidade podem ser feitas em qualquer lugar. Já teve caso aqui em que a pessoa vai procurar por recursos no Google, vai chegar aqui, vai ver um link para uma página com uma lista de links para os recursos que ela está procurando. E vai saber a qualidade dessa lista ao longo do tempo. É isso que queremos ser, um intermediário do Google?

### Listas Vs Recomendações

[Eu não sou contra recomendações](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/582/101). Eu deixei isso claro. Recomendações são on-topic aqui. Mas recomendações não são listas. Listas são, no máximo, recomendações que não deram certo.

E é difícil uma recomendação ou até mesmo ou assunto subjetivo dar certo. [Mesmo eu deixando claro que tipo de resposta não deveria ser colocada em uma pergunta subjetiva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/as-mensagens-de-erro-devem-se-desculpar), pessoas ignoraram o negrito e postaram o que não servia assim mesmo. Pena que nem todos podem ver as respostas excluídas. Mas boas recomendações podem dar certo. Recomendações não são listas de itens.

### Funcionamento dos sites SE

Mas talvez o problema vai além das listas. Eu realmente não consigo entender porque há uma tentativa, que eu vou chamar momentaneamente de oficial de transformar o SOpt em um experimento diferente de tudo o que se fez e ainda se faz na rede.

Eu gosto de ver o site mais inclusivo, mas não entendo porque temos que incluir listas ou outras coisas, que já ficaram claros que não são desejáveis. Conteúdo que é considerado indesejável pela da comunidade e é apoiado oficialmente pela equipe do SE como indesejável. Sempre foi assim e continua assim.

O Programmers começou cheio de listas. Elas foram fechadas e em sua maioria excluídas, principalmente após a intervenção dos principais líderes do site, na época, o Jeff, o Joel e o Robert. A comunidade queria listas mas a SE não queria. Nenhum site da rede deveria ser exceção.

Bom, isso poderia ter mudado. Mas se mudou. Porque agora não há um post no blog para deixar claro que mudou? A equipe sempre foi muito cuidadosa com isso. Sempre quis deixar claro o que pode e o que não pode. Principalmente quando há uma mudança na postura. Não vi em lugar algum qualquer referência oficial que há uma mudança na forma como os sites devem proceder com listas ou outros tipos de conteúdo que sempre foram considerados indesejáveis. Sejam eles colaborativos ou não. Usando CW ou não.

Só vi um posicionamento aqui que seria melhor aceitar esse tipo de conteúdo.

Mas teve um fato curioso recentemente. A criação do Software Recommendations. Lá o Robert Cartaino (Community Manager), [deixa claro que listas não são boas no site](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252/is-the-question-js-php-editor-software-acceptable/258#258) (sinto, nem todos terão acesso). Perguntas que possam gerar opiniões continuam sendo indesejáveis. Não vou entrar no mérito específico do que ele disse lá, mas me parece que ele está sendo até rígido demais para o meu gosto. Ele sabe o risco que aquele site corre e está ativamente participando de todas as discussões e deixando claro que a posição da equipe é a mesma para aquele site quanto é para todos os outros sites. O site foi permitido desde que não desvirtuasse a filosofia da rede.

Eu vi o próprio Robert fechando inúmeras propostas de site no Area 51 porque *potencialmente* o site poderia trazer problemas para o funcionamento normal do que se espera na rede. Algumas coisas que parecem ser incentivadas aqui. E isso me deixa muito confuso.

Já vi o Robert declarando explicitamente, até mesmo em pergunta minha, que ele acha as perguntas sobre livros ruins e elas deveriam ser desincentivadas.

Mas o SR não é o único site mais novo que fica claro que os procedimentos de todos os outros sites continuam valendo. Eu vejo que a equipe entende bem que a aceitação de certos tipos de perguntas afastam os especialistas e eles entendem que **o que faz os sites da rede serem diferentes são os especialistas**. Não é qualquer outra coisa. Não podemos ser arrogantes de achar que só porque estamos aqui o site será lindo, só porque usamos o software que o Jeff começou desenvolver em 2008, vamos ter conteúdo melhor do que outros sites. Só poderemos ter conteúdo melhor porque os especialistas estão aqui colaborando para ter esse conteúdo. Aceitar perguntas que irritam os especialistas não ajuda a causa do site.

Vendo que nada mudou na opinião da equipe sobre conteúdos muito amplos, que potencialmente trazem opiniões, comecei ter dúvidas se essa é a posição oficial da SE colocada aqui ou apenas a opinião pessoal do Gabe como mais um usuário do site. Nenhum problema em nenhum caso. Todos podem colocar sua opinião de como o site deveria ser. Mas eu gostaria de saber com mais clareza qual dos dois casos é esse post. Faz diferença.

### Preconceito

Quem procurar bem tudo o que eu faço, comento, chamo a atenção no chat, verá que **eu faço um esforço tremendo para salvar perguntas** que não parecem salváveis. Nunca fiz o mesmo esforço para uma lista porque não vejo elas como desejáveis. Não vejo como elas podem ser bons conteúdos e mesmo que possam ser, já disse onde elas devem estar.

Eu não sei se estou sendo preconceituoso com listas, até porque quem é preconceituoso, não percebe isso. Pode parecer porque eu digo que nenhuma pergunta que pede lista é boa. É generalização. Mas nem toda generalização é preconceito. Eu não preciso namorar homens para mostrar que não tenho preconceito com gays. Eu não preciso aceitar perguntas que pedem listas para mostrar que não tenho preconceito com elas. Eu aceito gays como amigos. Aceito listas como tag wikis, se elas se encaixam lá.

E na mesma linha vou usar um exemplo recente como o preconceito pode ocorrer de forma invertida. Boa parte do mundo está se levantando contra uma lei russa que teoricamente é contra gays. Ninguém se importou em analisar que a esmagadora maioria dos russos apoiam a lei e não procuram saber melhor sobre a lei, só saíram dando opinião baseado na desinformação da mídia. Não vou entrar no mérito da lei e os problemas que podem surgir dela, mas ela diz que não pode haver divulgação de relacionamentos não convencionais (homossexuais) **para crianças**. Só isso. Todo o resto é permitido. Saímos chamando o governo russo de preconceituoso porque aprovou uma lei por unanimidade, lei essa que nós **não conhecemos**, **não entendemos o contexto da sociedade** deles, mas nos achamos no direito de dar nosso pitaco. O preconceito nasce da falta de informação.

### Conclusão

Eu não sei como fazer listas darem certo.

Eu não acho que listas tenham espaço em um site de Q&A.

Nós temos um mecanismo que podem aceitar certas listas fora do centro do site.

Não vejo porque devemos experimentar aqui algo consagradamente problemático.

Acho os exemplos citados mostras claras que não funcionam bem, mesmo o exemplo que deveria indicar bom funcionamento.

Não sei porque temos que passar pela penúria de conviver com algo que normalmente é ruim para quem sabe salvar alguma coisa depois de dias, semanas, meses.

Não entendo porque estamos tendo que debater (debate é bom) como desvirtuar o que um site SE é.

Discordo radicalmente que qualquer conteúdo que é bom para os usuários é bom para o SOpt. Os usuários acham que cartoon favorito é bom para eles. Nem o Gabe consegue defender isso. Peguei o exemplo mais extremo, mas mas vale para qualquer conteúdo.

Não sou ingênuo de fazer uma ameaça, achando que sou fundamental para o site, porque sei muito bem que não sou nem importante. Mas tenho que expressar meu sentimento que o dia que o SOpt deixar de ser o que eu conheço dos sites do SE e se tornar mais um site, eu não terei mais interesse nele.

Paralela e adicionalmente eu ainda não sei qual é a relação da equipe com a comunidade neste site e ainda não sei uma série de coisas que gostaria de saber sobre o site. Ainda não entendo o posicionamento oficial da SE em relação a muitas coisas que estão sendo discutidas aqui. Mas pelo menos já temos um posicionamento nesta questão, mesmo ainda não sabendo claramente se ele é oficial ou pessoal.

Comment: Apologies for the English, but I need to say this myself:  Rest assured that Gabe speaks for the team here, and we are *very* involved in this approach. Gabe and I wrote the initial posts explaining the looser approach together, and a number of us, including me, have been regularly working with him on these issues. For now, our goal is simple: focus on asking, answering, and growing a great site. We encourage thinking about the rules, but it shouldn't be the focus - this is your time to enjoy asking, answering, and helping other programmers learn.

Comment: @Jaydles Why is this approach so different when compared to any other site on the network? And does this mean that anything goes, then? If not, how should we determine what is a valid question/answer? I don't see SE being much involved in discussing this with the community here.

Comment: @Jaydles You are more than welcome. We need more staff participation. It's a shame you can't understand directly the community feeling. Our focus is asking and answering. But we want the traditional SE rules either. It seems no one here wants be an experiment.

Comment: Eu dei a minha própria resposta, mas basicamente concordo que tag wiki é o caminho pra esse tipo de conteúdo. :)

Answer (score 13):

Uma reflexão <sub>que é grande demais para um comentário</sub>:

Não vejo como manter listas. Acho que desactualizam rápido e vão dar trabalho mais tarde a manter. Ainda assim coloquei-me dois cenários:

1 - Pensei na solução de ter uma lista em formato wiki. 1 pergunta e 1 resposta que a comunidade mantém. Mas parece-me má solução porque qualquer pessoa com minimo de reputação pode desvirtuar o conteúdo e tornar-se numa guerra de edits.

2 - Pensei na lista C++ e o que ali se vê são 104 respostas. Qual delas é a mais importante? A mais nova ou a mais votada? Um utilizador desacostumado pode pensar que é a mais votada, ou as primeiras da lista. Mas eu vejo que a segunda da lista foi editada em 2008. Quando ela estiver errada (ou deixar de ser atual) quanto tempo vai demorar a baixar ranking/votação?

Answer (score 12):

A lista de livros de C++ é um péssimo exemplo. A lista já foi fechada e reaberta quatro vezes, já foi trancada e destrancada, e foi discutida à exaustão no MSO. Ela só existe porque a comunidade em torno da tag C++ "adotou" a pergunta, resolveu cuidar dela, e brigou por ela. É uma exceção. Eu já mencionei anteriormente que não vejo problemas em termos aqui exceções semelhantes, contanto que exista uma comunidade mantendo a lista ativamente. Porém sou absolutamente contra fazer da exceção uma regra.

> Como fazer para incentivar a criação e manutenção de conteúdos colaborativos, evitando cair nos maus hábitos?

Eu realmente não sei. Se quiser transformar a lista de livros para iniciantes em Wiki Comunitário, podemos experimentar e ver o que acontece. Mas acho que neste momento do site ainda não temos massa crítica para atingir o nível de qualidade da lista de C++ (o que, aliás, leva tempo). E acho importantíssimo haver um *disclaimer* na pergunta alertando que é um experimento, e que pedidos de listas em geral não serão aceitos. Temos/tivemos vários no site já, e o resultado fala por si mesmo: basicamente listas de links.

Comment: Estou sem tempo para investir nisso agora mas um dos problemas que vejo em listas é que elas teriam que ser exceções. E acho que é péssimo ter que ficar criando exceções. Tem que ter um critério objetivo do que pode e o que não pode. Depois eu vou falar mais sobre o assunto. Quando tem que ficar debatendo demais se uma pergunta deve ser mantida ou não, essa pergunta é ruim. Claro que no começo é normal, porque ainda estamos aprendendo como nos comportar. Eu ainda vou responder a pergunta.

Comment: A lista de C++ ser fechada/aberta tantas vezes faz dela o melhor exemplo possível. Justamente pelo embate entre o conteúdo claramente aprovado pela comunidade e a adequação absoluta à regra. Seguir a regra ao pé da letra nunca daria a essa pergunta uma chance de ser útil. Não é uma questão de permitir todas as "perguntas de lista", mas como incentivar a criação de perguntas que sejam úteis, mesmo nesse molde.

Comment: Eu entendo sua intenção, @Gabe, mas acho que está pondo o carro na frente dos bois. Primeiro é preciso deixar claro quais são os problemas em relação às perguntas que pedem listas – [elas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4331) [tendem](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2724) a gerar respostas ruins (embora haja [exceções](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3218/74)). Quando isso estiver claro para a comunidade, aí sim podem-se abrir exceções, especialmente quando elas forem demandas da própria comunidade, como no caso do C++. Para haver exceções primeiro precisa haver regras. [continua]

Comment: A pergunta do C++ nem pergunta é, as respostas hoje são desincentivadas, e a orientação é discutir as indicações no chat, e, caso aprovadas, incluí-las no corpo da própria pergunta. Vai totalmente contra a ferramenta. O conteúdo é sim muito bom, e concordo que é bom termos conteúdo de qualidade aqui, mesmo que para isso seja preciso fugir um pouco às regras. Mas acho que primeiro é preciso delinear com clareza as regras. Senão vai ter gente entendendo que perguntas tipo lista (das ruins) são desejáveis.

Comment: @bfavaretto A idéia não é ter exceções. A questão é **reavaliar** de onde vem a indisposicão à perguntas de listas, e o que pode ser feito de *diferente* no nosso site. Nós temos uma oportunidade única de experimentar, discutir e entender o que pode criar uma boa comunidade, e eu não gostaria de ver essa chance posta de lado por seguir uma tradição sem compreender de onde ela vem, e onde ela pode ter errado, ou porque talvez não se aplique aqui. [continua]

Comment: Sim, as famigeradas *perguntas de lista* podem gerar **péssimas** perguntas, e esse normalmente é o caso. Mas se olharmos para os casos de sucesso, o que podemos aprender? Como podemos fazer diferente? **Devemos** tentar fazer diferente? Essas são as perguntas que eu acho que nós não fazemos

Comment: Devemos tentar fazer diferente? Eu creio que não.

Answer (score 11):

Creio que a "Construção Colaborativa de Conteúdo" é o Stack Overflow em si. O problema de ficar inventando novas mecânicas é querer transformar o SO em uma daquelas tevês que vinham com videocassete embutido (quando qualquer uma das coisas não funcionava bem, você ficava sem as duas coisas).

Eu não vejo com bons olhos tentar abraçar uma novidade fora da mecânica e da cultura do SO simplesmente pelo fato de que "aparenta ser bom". Traduzir documentação estrangeira, como a do SQLite também é bom, vamos fazer isso também? Que tal criarmos uma wiki para cada linguagem com aulas de programação? Poderiamos ter também uma seção de exemplos de código em várias linguagens, como o Rosetta Code.

É claro que estes exemplos são apenas uma brincadeira, mas só para alertar que o que pra uns pode parecer estranho (e tem mesmo que parecer), pode ser visto como uma ótima idéia quando não pensamos nos desdobramentos, e principalmente, no foco do que estamos fazendo.

<sub>Caso o meu tom tenha aparentado "incisivo" demais, me perdoem. A intenção é provocar pensamentos, e não pessoas.</sub>

Comment: +1 por deixar claro que a colaboração ocorre em todo o site. Que temos mecanismos suficientes para atingir cada objetivo.

Answer (score 8):

> Isto é um comentário à [proposta do Gabe e do Shog9](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/986), mas ficou grande demais para caber em um comentário.

Dadas as ferramentas que o sistema oferece, manter as listas de livros nos tag wikis parece ser mesmo a melhor solução, como a comunidade [havia](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/826/74) [sugerido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/845/74) (não somente para listas de livros, mas também em [outros casos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-minimo-reproduzivel-em-r#comment1644_824)). Não vejo problemas nem em colocar ali links para cursos online, como os do Codeacademy. Quanto a livros sobre programação que não se encaixem em nenhuma tag existente, talvez eles justifiquem a existência de uma ou outra meta-tag como "iniciantes" ou "aprendizagem", embora eu não simpatize muito com a ideia de elas existirem.

Porém ainda vejo alguns problemas na solução que foi dada (manter a pergunta aberta, trancada), que discuto brevemente a seguir.

#### A pergunta, e principalmente a resposta, como estão hoje, parecem fora de lugar

A resposta é bastante incomum se comparada com os demais conteúdos do site, e mesmo dos outros sites da rede. É uma meta-resposta, e faria mais sentido como um item de FAQ, na central de ajuda ou no meta. Ela não responde à pergunta, mas indica onde encontrar a resposta e, principalmente, como agregar novos conteúdos aos tag wikis.

Entendo que seu objetivo seja funcionar como um farol, uma sinalização de onde esse conteúdo está, já que os tag wikis são "invisíveis" – pouco conhecidos e mal classificados em resultados de pesquisa do Google, além de terem pouco destaque visual dentro do próprio site (para chegar a um wiki, primeiro é preciso passar pelo fragmento/excerto).

Mas é um farol estranho. A trava/bloqueio que foi posta na pergunta não permite que ela receba votos nem comentários. A resposta permite ambos, o que mitiga um pouco o problema. Mas a pergunta, que a SE considera de valor "indiscutível", fica em desvantagem em relação às demais perguntas do site: a comunidade não pode dar mais ou menos peso a ela por meio dos votos, nem medir sua importância com base na quantidade de votos que ela tem.

Também não fica claro para os usuários que ela não pode ser votada (só ao tentar votar é que aparece uma mensagem de erro informativa). O sistema de votação é um dos principais diferenciais do site, e o fato de a pergunta não pode contar com ele pesa contra a solução encontrada. Talvez fosse melhor deixá-la fechada em vez de bloqueada, mas suspeito que isso possa ser desvantajoso em termos de SEO (não sei exatamente como isso é tratado).

Já a resposta permite comentários e edições, porém a resposta em si não contém a lista de livros, então comentários sobre isso (como sugestões de novos livros) parecem fora de lugar. Edições também não poderiam lidar com a lista de livros em si, somente com o conteúdo atual da resposta, que é um texto de ajuda. O que nos leva ao próximo ponto:

#### A comunidade não possui boas ferramentas para manter esse tipo de conteúdo

A construção coletiva de uma lista de recursos depende de dois fatores:

- A existência de especialistas no assunto dispostos a contribuir.
- A articulação e o debate entre esses especialistas para que definam a melhor forma de organizar esse conteúdo, e os critérios para seleção dos recursos.

O segundo fator é fundamental para a geração de conteúdo de qualidade, mas a única ferramenta que o sistema oferece para debater o conteúdo de um tag wiki é o chat. É melhor que nada (e de fato foi a ferramenta adotada pela comunidade que mantém a lista de livros de C++), porém não é uma solução óbvia.

Deixo aqui duas sugestões que podem melhorar um pouco a situação:

- Inclusão de um link no tag wiki que leve diretamente ao chat, de preferência a uma sala especial criada para discussão daquele wiki específico (a sala poderia ser criada automaticamente caso ainda não exista).
- Criação de uma seção de discussão do wiki, semelhante ao que existe na Wikipedia. Imagino que isso seja mais dicífil de implementar, mas me parece uma solução melhor do que usar o chat.

Comment: Concordo com você sobre os votos. Vamos pensar num alternativa.

Answer (score 7):

Na minha opinião o motivo das listas não serem desejadas no formato tradicional de nenhum site do grupo StackExchange pode não ser sempre muito claro, mas é justificável. Apesar de o conteúdo ser eventualmente muito importante para a comunidade (e isso é inegável principalmente em exemplos como o do C++ referido), o formato Q&A simplesmente *não é apropriado* para esse tipo de conteúdo.

Perguntas com listas (e até mesmo certos pedidos de recomendação) têm o potencial de gerar um número muito grande de respostas, que podem mesmo ter em sua grande maioria bastante qualidade além da mera indicação de links. Mas, o objetivo de um Q&A como o SO ou o SOPT, por exemplo, é criar material de referência para que futuros interessados em conteúdo possam buscar dúvidas ou problemas e encontrar soluções *facilmente*. Ter de navegar e ler centenas de respostas não ajuda nada nessa intenção; pelo contrário, causa bastante dificuldade e torna difícil as tarefas de gerenciar e de buscar o conteúdo.

O que faz o formato Q&A funcionar e verdadeiramente facilita a busca de soluções a problemas diversos (e que é uma grande sacada, em minha modesta opinião) é a inspiração em um princípio básico de interação de comunidades biológicas chamado [Estigmergia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigmergy). A ideia é que a atuação da comunidade reforça gradualmente aquilo que é mais relevante para a própria comunidade. Essa metáfora do feromônio se inicia aqui quando o OP aceita uma resposta. Essa é simplesmente *a maior indicação* de que o conteúdo foi útil, porque garantidamente satisfez ao menos um indivíduo da colônia (e esse é um dos motivos pelo qual eu sou relativamente contra limitar o escopo de perguntas classificadas como muito pessoais). A metáfora se segue com as votações (tanto positivas como negativas) que ao se acumularem produzem uma "visão geral da colônia" sobre o quão útil o conteúdo é. Naturalmente isso leva tempo, pois os votos realmente importantes não são aqueles do tipo "votei porque tenho votos sobrando e achei bacaninha", e sim aqueles do tipo "tava f.did. com um problema, procurei aqui e achei essa resposta que realmente me ajudou".

Em listas esse mecanismo talvez não funcione porque:

1. O OP não tem como "escolher" uma resposta. Muitas delas podem ser igualmente válidas. De fato, provavelmente o OP não tem um problema claro e objetivo, mas sim uma vontade de aprender algo, ou uma curiosidade. Isso é válido, mas o julgamento da comunidade vai ser tão amplo quanto a pergunta.
2. Os votos da comunidade são muito diluídos entre as inúmeras respostas. O "mecanismo de atração" às respostas com mais feromônio faz com que as respostas mais votadas sejam exibidas na frente, desestimulando a leitura das demais (principalmente se o leitor tiver de navegar em 4 ou 5 páginas para isso). Dessa forma, há muito trabalho e pouca recompensa para quem posta respostas e, principalmente, para quem procura por elas.

Bom, alguém já mencionou que uma comunidade (ou parte dela) realmente interessada pode garantir que o conteúdo seja bacana. A solução encontrada pela comunidade C++ no SO foi utilizar o chat para receber sugestões e moderar a edição do post. Isso funciona, e é de fato um trabalho coletivo que gera conteúdo importante e relevante (vide a Wikipidia) e que também inclui um caráter estigmérgico envolvido no fato de que posts com mais edições são mostrados como ativos. Mas, essa abordagem de trabalho simplesmente *não utiliza* os recursos de votação que tornaram o SO o que é hoje. Eu acredito que por esse único motivo, esse tipo de pergunta não pertence a um site como o SO e também não deveria pertencer ao SOPT.

Entretanto, isso não quer dizer que não devemos estimular a comunidade a construir e manter esse tipo de conteúdo, desde que o faça em lugares que julgarmos apropriados. Uma *Community Wiki* pode funcionar, mas assuntos como sugestões de livros, por exemplo, parecem funcionar melhor nas definições dos rótulos (*tags*) sobre esses assuntos.

Answer (score 6):

Vou apenas citar o disclaimer ao final da pergunta que foi usada como exemplo:

> This question has historical significance, but is **not a good example of an appropriate question**. Read and learn from this post, but **please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions**.

;)

O autor da pergunta também pede que não sejam dadas novas respostas.

Minha opinião: podemos fazer como fizeram lá. Manter uma pergunta porque ela será mantida pelo Wiki. E porque, sempre que alguém fizer a mesma pergunta, podemos marcar como duplicata e apontar para a **3C oficial** (gostei do termo). Mas devemos colocar um *disclaimer* similar ao aqui citado.

Outra ideia relacionada: precisamos de um blog do *SOePT*, que pode ter posts sobre bom material educativo. Acho mais apropriado para uma lista dessas.

Comment: Eu acho que devemos ter um blog do SOpt para termos algumas outras formas de colocar algumas informações importantes que não cabem em um site de Q&A. Mas isso é algo que ainda vamos ter que aguardar para ver se rola.

Answer (score 6):

Conforme expus em [uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291/215) à pergunta "O que fazer com perguntas que podem ter múltiplas respostas?", creio que exista um formato que possa ser adequado para se representar listas, sem desvirtuar a engine do SE (i.e. ainda aproveitando o que ela faz de melhor):

- Se uma "pergunta" é a união de várias outras perguntas menores, em primeiro lugar cada uma dessas perguntas deve ser feita em separado. Ex.:

  - [Diferença na utilização Indice Unique e Unique Constraint no Informix?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/diferenca-na-utilizacao-indice-unique-e-unique-constraint-no-informix?lq=1)
  - [Diferença na utilização Indice Unique e Unique Constraint no Sql Server?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/823/diferenca-na-utilizacao-indice-unique-e-unique-constraint-no-sql-server)
  - [Diferença na utilização Indice Unique e Unique Constraint no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/793/diferenca-na-utilizacao-indice-unique-e-unique-constraint-no-mysql)
  - [Quando usar uma unique constraints vs indices únicos no Oracle?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/515/quando-usar-uma-unique-constraints-vs-indices-unicos-no-oracle)

  Isso vale inclusive para perguntas de recomendação ([se a comunidade optar por aceitá-las](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/57/215)). Mais sobre isso adiante.
- Depois pode-se fazer uma pergunta que englobe todas elas. Por exemplo, "Diferença da utilização de Indice Unique e Unique Constraint". Essa pergunta poderia ser respondida normalmente, como se fosse uma pergunta conceitual (sem entrar no mérito das tecnologias específicas), ou receber uma auto-resposta community wiki, conforme a situação.
- A resposta aceita seria então convertida em community wiki (se já não o for) e receber os links para cada pergunta individual - de modo a facilitar a busca por soluções em uma tecnologia específica.

Se vale a pena fazer isso ou não? Não sei dizer... Mas se fosse feito (i.e. se alguém fizer uma pergunta nesse formato), não me oporia. Creio que às vezes é bom ter uma pergunta conceitual "acompanhando" uma pergunta específica, para evitar que um capítulo inteiro seja escrito para responder perguntas bastante semelhantes. Ex.: o que aconteceria se eu perguntasse hoje "qual a maneira correta de se salvar senhas no Django?" - a resposta certa ou vai ter um link para [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215) ou repetirá boa parte do conteúdo da mesma (e **ainda assim** mesmo depois de ler a pergunta conceitual eu ainda posso precisar de ajuda para colocar isso em prática na minha plataforma de escolha).

#### OK, mas isso se aplica a perguntas de recomendação como?

Concordo com todos que uma pergunta "o que me recomendam?" é problemática em vários níveis, e não dá para ser respondida usando o formato simples 1 pergunta N respostas. Mas imagine que alguém pergunte algo como:

> **Alguém me recomendaria o "Aprendendo Django no Planeta Terra"?**
>
> Preciso aprender Django para um projeto novo, e me indicaram o site ["Aprendendo Django no Planeta Terra"](http://www.aprendendodjango.com/), que parece ter um tutorial passo-a-passo, com capturas de tela e tudo mais, e está todo em português (importante pra mim, que não domino bem o inglês). Alguém conhece esse site, acha que seria indicado para quem tem pouca ou nenhuma experiência com Python e está entrando em contato com o Django pela primeira vez?

(Nota: isso não é uma pergunta 100% fictícia, realmente uma pessoa que trabalha comigo me apareceu com esse site, do nada. Só que em vez de pedir recomendação, ela me recomendou - depois de já ter gasto muito tempo com ele. Se ela tivesse me perguntado antes...)

Nesse formato, eu julgo que a pergunta é:

1. Respondível: quem tem experiência com Django e já leu - ou está disposto a ler - o tutorial em questão será capaz de dizer objetivamente se ele é bom ou não e por que. Minha resposta por exemplo seria:

   > Não. Embora à primeira vista a qualidade do material me pareça boa, ele está bastante defasado: logo que começa a explicar sobre a configuração do projeto, notei que ele usa o formato do Django 1.1. Houve mudanças significativas a partir do Django 1.2, e a versão corrente já é a 1.6. Sugiro procurar um material alternativo (infelizmente, não tenho nada de bom a sugerir em português).

   Outros poderiam dar respostas diferentes - por exemplo salientando que a explicação da plataforma como um todo é de fato boa, desde que você fique atento às diferenças entre versões. Etc.
2. Avaliável: como não há "mistura de conceitos", quem lê minha resposta pode avaliar se ela é útil ou não (votando positivo ou negativo), se ela responde a pergunta ou não (sinalizando de acordo), etc. E se houver mais de uma resposta, elas são comparáveis entre si - pois estão falando da mesma coisa. Se um estivesse recomendando o site A e o outro o site B aí ficaria mais difícil saber qual a resposta é a "melhor".

Dessa forma, não creio **a princípio** que esse tipo de pergunta seja indesejável no site (embora meu sexto sentido me alerta que isso poderia abrir as portas pra Spam). E tal qual o exemplo anterior, várias dessas perguntas poderiam ser "consensadas" em uma só, por exemplo:

> **Que tutorial de Django em português seria recomendado para um iniciante?**
>
> **P:** Preciso aprender Django e blá blá blá (bem contextualizada, de preferência). O que me recomendariam nessa situação?
>
> **R:** Você precisa de um material que cubra as duas principais funcionalidades do Django - seu ORM e seu sistema de templates - além da arquitetura geral e da forma de instalação/configuração. Segue links:
>
> - link
> - link
> - ["Aprendendo Django no Planeta Terra"][link para **a pergunta**] (Nota: material meio antigo)
> - link

Observação: a ordem aqui não importa - a pergunta de recomendação geral pode ter aparecido primeiro, e a específica depois. Ou seja, "responder à pergunta geral" não seria simplesmente adcionar uma nova resposta - e sim adicionar uma nova pergunta que por sua vez estaria sob o escrutínio da comunidade como um todo.

Comment: Nota: coloquei essa "sugestão" porque não sou contra mudanças nem experimentações, mas **não estou** - na falta uma palavra melhor - *championing* essa ideia... (em particular no que trata de recomendações)

Comment: Acho noção de que as perguntas de lista/recomendação agem como condensadores de diversas perguntas menores interessante. Talvez haja uma resposta, se olharmos por esse caminho.