# Como criar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R

Tags: debate

O site já tem um documento oficial, que é a base para o requisito, e deve ser observado em qualquer assunto, e em R não poderia ser diferente:

[Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Como complemento, ao perguntar algo ou pedir ajuda à comunidade do `R`, o ideal é trazer exemplo reproduzível do erro ou da dúvida. Melhor ainda, um exemplo reproduzível mínimo, que tente reproduzir o erro com a menor quantidade de código possível.

O que deve ter em exemplo reproduzível mínimo? Que informações devem ser colocadas? Quais funções do `R` podem ajudar a fazer um exemplo reproduzível?

Comment: Editei para acrescentar a informação oficial, mas não quis interferir muito no seu texto, talvez seja o caso de você revisar para ficar mais no seu estilo o resto do texto. Talvez dê até para deixar menos repetitivo como base no link.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Conteúdo

Um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R deve ter os seguintes conteúdos:

1. Um pequeno conjunto de dados;
2. O menor código possível que seja **executável** e que reproduza o erro no pequeno conjunto de dados mencionado;
3. As informações sobre a versão do `R` e do sistema em que está rodando o código, bem como dos pacotes utilizados;
4. Se for utilizar dados aleatórios, informar o *seed* com a função `set.seed()`;
5. Quando pertinente, o resultado que você espera obter.

Os exemplos das páginas de ajuda das funções do `R` podem ser de grande valia para ter uma noção da estrutura de um exemplo mínimo reproduzível. Em geral, os códigos dos exemplos da ajuda do `R` satisfazem a esses requisitos.

#### Produzindo o conjunto de dados

Para usar seu próprio conjuto de dados, a função `dput()`, juntamente com `head()` pode ser bastante útil. Por exemplo o código abaixo fornece as 10 primeiras observações da base de dados `iris` já com a estrutura necessária para "remontar" a base de dados. Assim, para quem for tentar responder a sua pergunta, basta copiar e colar o código em `structure()`.

```
dput(head(iris,10))
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 
5, 4.4, 4.9), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 
3.4, 2.9, 3.1), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 
1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", 
"Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Reproduzindo os dados:

```
dados<-structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 
    5, 4.4, 4.9), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 
    3.4, 2.9, 3.1), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 
    1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", 
    "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"), row.names = c(NA, 
    10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Uma solução menos ideal do que esta seria fornecer os dados em formato texto, como, por exemplo, no caso abaixo:

```
texto <- "Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa"
```

Neste caso, o usuário que for responder sua pergunta pode remontar a base de dados utilizando a função `read.table()`:

```
dados <- read.table(text=texto)
```

Outra forma de produzir um conjunto de dados é gerando **valores aleatórios**, por exemplo, com a função `rnorm()` (você também pode gerar de outras distribuições sem ser a normal, caso seja pertinente) ou com a função `sample()` para uma amostragem de valores de algum vetor. Um caso útil pode ser a função `letters()`, para gerar caracteres ou fatores. Neste caso, não esqueça de fornecer a `seed` para que o exemplo seja reproduzível.

Exemplo:

```
set.seed(1)
dados <- data.frame( x= rnorm(10), y=sample(letters, 10))
dados
                    x y
1  -0.626453810742333 y
2   0.183643324222082 f
3  -0.835628612410047 p
4    1.59528080213779 c
5   0.329507771815361 z
6  -0.820468384118015 i
7   0.487429052428485 a
8   0.738324705129217 h
9   0.575781351653492 x
10 -0.305388387156356 v
```

Outras funções interessantes neste caso são as funções do tipo `as`, como  `as.factor()`, `as.Date()` etc, para você converter os dados para o formato necessário.

#### Produzindo o código mínimo

Tente identificar a menor parte necessária do seu código que gere o erro ou a dúvida que você tem.  Antes de enviar o código, certifique-se de que você elencou os pacotes necessários para que ele seja reproduzível. Para isso, é bom testar o seu código após reiniciar a sessão do `R`, para ter certeza de que tudo o que é necessário está lá.

Exemplo:

```
 library(lattice) # a biblioteca utilizada
    set.seed(1) # a seed
    dados <- data.frame( x= as.character(rnorm(10)), y=sample(letters, 10)) #o conjunto de dados
    densityplot(as.numeric(dados$x))
    as.numeric(dados$x)
[1]  2  5  4 10  6  3  7  9  8  1
```

Pergunta: "Estou tentando fazer um gráfico de densidade com o `lattice` como no código acima, porque quando converto os dados para numeric eles viram 2, 5, 4 ... e não permanecem como os dados originais do `rnorm`?"

#### Resultado esperado

Às vezes o seu problema não é um erro *stricto sensu*, mas você não consegue fazer a função retornar aquilo que você gostaria. Deste modo, é interessante produzir um protótipo do que seria o resultado esperado. Nessas horas, vale ser criativo. Veja um exemplo do SO em inglês, em que o usuário gostaria de colocar o p-valor na tabela latex, e indicou no paint onde gostaria que fosse:

[image: Explicando o que quer]

#### Informações do sistema

Por fim, quando necessário, você pode fornecer as informações do seu sistema com `sessionInfo()`, que dá informações detalhadas da sua seção. No meu caso, essas informações foram:

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lattice_0.20-15

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.0.1  tools_3.0.1
```