# Migrar essa pergunta para o Site Principal

Tags: debate, status-recusado, pergunta-específica, meta, migração

Gostaria de tirar essa pergunta (
[Como criar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/825#825)) daqui do meta e migrar para o site principal, como uma ***community wiki.*** Acho que lá ela terá mais destaque e será mais fácil de ser encontrada pelos ***usuários novos*** de R (por exemplo, se ele ordenar perguntas por votos etc) e assim cumprirá melhor sua função. Além disso, a rigor ***me parece que essa é uma pergunta de programação***, cujas respostas envolvem o uso de código para construir um exemplo reproduzível em uma linguagem específica.

O que acham?

PS: Eu entendo que conceitualmente é possível argumentar que essa é uma pergunta do Meta (apesar de tratar espeficiamente de como construir um exemplo reproduzível em R, o que é uma pergunta de programação). Entretanto, será que aqui ela terá mais chances de cumprir seu papel para educar os usuários novos de R? Um usuário desse dificilmente vai entrar no meta no começo, e se entrar, não existe uma tag `r` no meta. No site principal, acredito que as chances de o usuário acabar se deparando com a pergunta são muito maiores.

Comment: Estava contra de primeira, mas não tenho mais certeza. Lembrei desta aqui: [Como podemos lidar com as “listas”?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/819/201)

Comment: Acho que o link de como criar um exemplo em R poderia estar na wiki da tag, materias e informações úteis geralmente ficam lá. Isso independente da pergunta ser ou não migrada.

Comment: Concordo com o @perdeu, e já tinha sugerido isso na própria pergunta. A informação cairia bem mesmo na na wiki da tag [tag:r].

Comment: Também concordo com o @perdeu. Acho que a pergunta não faz muito sentido no site principal, mas é suficientemente importante pra ser facilmente referenciada pelos usuários de R. Parece mesmo que o melhor local é a tag de wiki.

Comment: Respondendo ao [comentário da outra pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r#comment7354_824): eu acho mesmo que o lugar disso é na *[wiki da tag r](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info)*. Não vi você se manifestar sobre essa opção ainda, o que acha dela?

Comment: @bfavaretto um link na wiki poderia ser, agora o conteúdo na wiki acho que não faz sentido, pois outras pessoas podem colocar outras respostas sugerindo novas funções etc

Comment: @CarlosCinelli, as wikis de tags são sub-aproveitadas, quase ninguém sabe que existe, mas o correto é ir fazendo manutenção e atualização do seu conteúdo. . . . Tá faltando no nosso Meta uma campanha **Adote uma Tag**...

Answer (score 7):

A pergunta como está não funciona no site principal. Não é uma pergunta sobre R, é sobre como perguntar no site. Mas eu concordo que a resposta possui bastante informação relevante sobre R.

Eu enxergo duas maneiras de ter esse conteúdo no site principal, já que no meta não parece agradar à comunidade dessa tag:

1. Incluir todo o conteúdo da resposta na [tag wiki de R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).
2. Incluir uma versão resumida da resposta na tag wiki de R, e usar parte do conteúdo sobre a linguagem em novas pergunta e respostas, que podem ser citadas na tag wiki. Por exemplo, a primeira seção, *Produzindo o conjunto de dados*, rende fácil uma pergunta + resposta. A parte sobre como pegar as informações do sistema também. Remover apenas essas duas seções já reduziria bastante o tamanho do que iria para a tag wiki.

Comment: Eu gostei mais da segunda abordagem, para a wiki não ficar muito longa.