# Como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R?

Tags: debate

De acordo com a [definição da tag R no Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info),

> O R é um ambiente e linguagem de programação de código aberto para computação estatística, bioinformática e gráficos.

Sendo uma linguagem cujo principal uso se dá em computação estatística, é natural que ela seja muito utilizada em análise de dados. Muitas vezes, o autor da pergunta possui estes dados armazenados em seu computador.

Desta forma, para que uma pergunta sobre `R` seja bem recebida e tenha atenção o suficiente da comunidade,

- como o usuário pode compartilhar os dados analisados (ou uma parte deles) com a comunidade?
- quais são as principais características de uma boa pergunta sobre `R`?
- existe algo que deve ser evitado em uma pergunta sobre `R`?

Enfim, como fazer uma pergunta sobre `R` de modo que ela possa ser entendida, reproduzida e respondida pelos demais usuários?

Comment: Acredito que essa pergunta seria mais adequada no meta

Comment: Entendo este ponto de vista, mas discordo dele. [Há uma pergunta similar a esta no SO original, na tag r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Não que tenhamos que ser idênticos ao SO original, mas acho que muitas coisas que servem para lá, servem para cá também. Por fim, creio que minha pergunta pertence ao tópico _dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software_ da Central de Ajuda.

Comment: Concordo com o @MarcusNunes. A questão é sobre como implementar especificamente no `R` as diretrizes gerais sobre perguntas reprodutíveis.

Comment: Essa pergunta já tinha sido feita aqui e acabaram migrando para o meta (eu fui contra). Na época eu avisei para o pessoal  que eventualmente ela voltaria https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r

Comment: Essa pergunta tinha que ser comunidade wiki na página principal e não no meta. Vou lançar a discussão novamente.

Comment: Discussão aqui https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6704/duas-vezes-uma-pergunta-sobre-r-veio-erroneamente-para-o-meta

Comment: @DanielFalbel, só não marquei assim ontem porque não achei esta pergunta na comunidade principal. Mais uma razão para uma das duas voltar

Comment: Marcus: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-funções-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A base de uma boa pergunta reprodutível é que deve ser possível que o **seu problema¹ apareça como problema para aqueles que irão tentar entendê-lo e resolvê-lo**.

## Linhas gerais

Para que possamos reproduzir seu problema o seguinte passo-a-passo pode ser seguido:

1. Tente reproduzir seu problema em sua máquina antes de enviá-lo ao StackOverflow.
2. Forneça o código que produziu (e que deverá reproduzir no computador alheio) o comportamento que motiva a pergunta.
3. Forneça dados capazes de reproduzir o problema.
4. Forneça o resultado esperado pelo código fornecido em 1.

## 1. Como reproduzir meu problema?

Abra um novo script e um novo ambiente. Se você estiver utilizando o RStudio você pode iniciar um nova seção clicando em `Session` na barra superior e depois `New Session`. Caso esteja usando o `R` (Rgui, R pela linha de comando, etc), basta abrir o programa mais um vez.

Neste novo ambiente copie o script original e vá rodando linha por linha até que se depare com o problema novamente. Este método permite isolar o problema nos seus determinantes fundamentais. Caso você esteja trabalhando em um script de 200 linhas, mas o erro acontece na linha 53, não há motivo para compartilhar as 147 linhas que se seguem ao erro e provavelmente boa parte das primeiras 53 linhas também podem ser excluídas do código que será partilhado.

Uma vez identificada a origem do problema, forneça aquela linha de código e **apenas as demais linhas necessárias para reproduzir o problema**. Digamos que o erro foi encontrado em:

```
sum(x)
```

Neste caso é necessário que também saibamos o que é `x`, ou seja, forneça o(s) objeto(s) `x` **no estado em que eles entraram na chamada da função** (ver item 3).

## 2. Como compartilhar meu código?

A maneira mais adequada é copiando e colando o **texto do seu código**. Parece trivial, mas [essa não é a única forma de fornecer o código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/43953).

Caso esteja se deparando com um erro ou aviso, forneça a mensagem.

```
sum(x)
Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

## 3. Como fornecer dados?

Como comentado acima, seus dados devem ser fornecidos no estado em que estavam quando o erro ocorreu. Para isso quando se deparar com o erro, utilize a função  `dput` para fornecer seu objeto tal como ele se encontra.

```
dput(x)
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
```

A função `dput` permite que seu objeto seja recriado em outra máquina, mesmo que ele tenha sido obtido de uma base de dados ou arquivo ou outra forma. Caso seu objeto seja muito grande utilize `dput(head(objeto, 30))` ou alguma outra forma de limitar o tamanho do objeto.

Há aqueles que gostam de fornecer as linhas de código que criaram o objeto. Ocorre que entre iniciantes é muito comum alterar o objeto posteriormente e, portante, o estado do objeto na linha original e na linha que gerou o erro podem (eu diria devem) mudar. Por esta razão utilizar `dput` garante maior reprodutibilidade do código e deve ser preferido.

Este é o caso no exemplo de erro que estou utilizando aqui:

```
x <- 1:5
x <- c(x, '6')
sum(x)
Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Caso seu código precise de alguma simulação, utilize `set.seed(1)` (ou qualquer outro número) para garantir que os resultados serão o mesmo em sua máquina e na daqueles que pretendem auxiliá-lo.

## 4. Como compartilhar o resultado esperado?

Isto pode ser feito de muitas formas. É possível utilizar um link ou imagem que contém o resultado esperado (no caso de um gráfico, [como este exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103995/como-fazer-um-gr%C3%A1fico-de-bolhas-cada-uma-delas-preenchida-de-acordo-com-uma-pro)). Também é possível descrever com palavras o que espera, como [neste caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257812/como-criar-grupos-de-3-palavras-em-um-texto-de-tamanho-aleat%C3%B3rio/257934#257934).

---

1: Problema aqui não precisa ser entendido como um erro, mas simplesmente como a motivação da pergunta

Answer (score 9):

Um requisito importante, que está contemplado na resposta do Tomás (parte 1), mas não está especificada é a importância de colocar no código da pergunta os pacotes que são necessários para reproduzir o problema. O `R` tem uma quantidade muita grande de pacotes e dificulta ter que pesquisar em qual pacote determinada função utilizada está. Então, no início do código, caso tenha sido necessário:

```
library(PACOTE1)
library(PACOTE2)
...
library(PACOTEN)
```