# Perguntas em R podem depender de um link externo para o conjunto de dados?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Não sei R, portanto não tenho certeza se estou fazendo a coisa certa.

De acordo com [Como criar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/824/100416), o primeiro requisito para um MCVE em R é:

> 1. Um pequeno conjunto de dados;

E algumas perguntas incluem um link para o conjunto de dados, ficando por exemplo:

> dados <- read.csv2("seu-link-aqui")

Mas isso me parece não ser correto, já que, se a pergunta precisa de um conjunto de dados para ter o MCVE, deste modo a pergunta estaria dependendo de um link externo. E isso me chamou a atenção hoje porque vi algumas edições **em respostas** onde o autor da pergunta remove o link para a base de dados - e este link já não funciona, retorna o erro 404.

As sugestões de edição que encontrei são: [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/356416), [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/356411), [3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/356415). Talvez tenham mais. Fui investigar e as perguntas já não tinham o link para os dados, que foi removido por edição do autor.

Há também [edições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/501231/revisions) onde o autor da pergunta remove os dados que foram colocados como texto.

#### Minhas impressões são:

1. As perguntas que dependem de um link externo deveriam ter sido fechadas desde sua criação;
2. As edições devem ser rejeitadas agora, pois perde-se o contexto de onde os dados vêm (seja os dados de um link, seja os descritos como "texto" / código);
3. As perguntas que dependiam de um link devem ser fechadas agora, já que não possuem mais um MCVE;
4. As perguntas que apenas tiveram o código dos dados removido, devem ter as edições revertidas.

Estou correto nesta análise? Nesse caso específico, parece uma tentativa de burlar as regras do site, criando uma pergunta (quase) correta e, após conseguir a resposta, há edições de forma a "vandalizar" a pergunta/resposta, tornando-as um *helpdesk*.

Comment: Tenho a impressão que já vi uma duplicata por aqui, mas não encontrei.

Comment: Pelo que vi, algumas edições são para remover "dados sigilosos", então ele nem deveria ter colocado pra começo de conversa. [Deixei um comentário em uma das perguntas orientando sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/501220#comment960948_501220). Já no caso mais geral, vale a resposta do Maniero mesmo...

Comment: @hkotsubo todas as edições que vi são assim. Não vi todas as perguntas do usuário, mas a edição mais antiga que citei nesta pergunta é de um ano atrás, com este motivo. Por isso acho que é uma tentativa de _helpdesk_, onde são colocados dados para a pergunta não ser fechada, e depois removidos. Cometer esse erro vez ou outra é aceitável, mas com frequência me parece abuso do sistema.

Comment: @hkotsubo exatamente.

Comment: Eu ainda estou em dúvida se foi só "despreparo" (colocar dados sigilosos na internet e não saber que eles continuam no histórico de edições), ou má fé (coloca os dados e remove depois de ter a resposta - nesse caso, usando o "sigilo" como desculpa), ou um pouco de ambos. Mas enfim, em todo caso é mau uso do sistema...

Comment: Me parece que a maioria (a maioria mesmo) dessas perguntas só servem para o AP e **não** servem para aprendizado, as perguntas são basicamente *suporte técnico*, ou seja, ao responder essas perguntas, com ou sem dados para reproduzir, só servirá para o AP mesmo... Tenho notado um forte apoio ao *suporte técnico gratuito* em **[tag:r]** por parte de quem responde e só uma ou outra pergunta nessa tag foram úteis para agregar conhecimento ao site e servirão para futuros visitantes, apenas exceções.

Comment: R tem um problema generalizado no site. Já teve grupo que veio com história maluca de que "a comunidade R tem regras próprias", como se qualquer grupo fosse isento das regras básicas (que fique claro: _isso non ecziste!_) - Tivemos até problema com votos, mas não posso detalhar. O fato é que a gente acaba deixando passar por falta de experiência em R, aí requer mais análise (da minha parte, por falta de prática ao menos), então na dúvida acaba passando muito helpdesk. Quem entende e percebeu que é coisa duplicada, muito específica, ou com dados insuficientes pode ajudar com votos e fechamento.

Comment: As regras são as mesmas para qualquer assunto, e postagens que dependam de links sem dúvida é pra fechar de imediato, independente do assunto. Essa própria postagem do exemplo verificável deveria ter logo no começo um aviso de que é um complemento em cima do documento [oficial do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (que vale para todos) - EDIT: acrescentei.

Comment: @Bacco também não conheço R, geralmente pulo as questões. Resolvi analisar essas porque encontrei essa inconsistência por conta das edições. Votei para fechar algumas, já que o meu voto é apenas um de três, e deixei um comentário para que a comunidade entenda o voto de fechamento e vote de acordo. Entendo que para moderadores em caso de dúvida é mais complicado, já que precisa de um único voto de moderador...

Comment: Sobre seus quatro pontos, os primeiros três são indiscutíveis, "sim", "sim" e "sim". O 4 vamos ter que analisar caso a caso, as que forem fechadas não acho que precise reverter, pois o objetivo não é criar problema para o autor, apenas respeitar o objetivo do site (regras são só um meio, o que importa é o objetivo real delas) e preservar a licença em conteúdo que vai ser eliminado é desnecessário (burocracia só é bom quando cumpre o objetivo real, mas onde dá pra acomodarmos todos os interesses, melhor né). Inclusive, dados de login externo já estou retirando alguns.

Comment: @Bacco justamente. A questão é que a comunidade como um todo, principalmente os que frequentam e entendem mais de R, precisa cuidar para que essas respostas sejam fechadas de imediato pelos motivos bem demonstrados.

Comment: Não sei se é relevante, mas vou colocar minha experiência como usuário do site: Eu venho de linguagens como Basic, Assembly(Z80,MC6800,x86), Pascal, C, Lisp, Clipper, Delphi, Java, VB, VBA, C#, ASP,... Eu evolui em PHP, HTML, Javascript, CSS, C, C++ e Tecnologias Web graças ao conteúdo do site. Eu aprendi a programar em Python e Typescript graças ao conteúdo do site. Estou aprendendo React  graças ao conteúdo do site. Eu não consigo aprender a programar em R usando o conteúdo do site, a maioria das questões não se tratam de conceitos e sim de erros de parâmetros e problemas específicos dos APs

Comment: @AugustoVasques é o que eu vejo, que bom um relato pessoal de alguém que tenta usar esse conteúdo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Nenhuma postagem pode depender de *links* externos

Cai na questão do *link* desaparecer e a pergunta passa não mais fazer sentido. Então não é aceitável. O ideal é fechar o quanto antes. Fica o alerta para todos fechadores, começando por mim.

Eu acho que se precisa de dados para responder a pergunta não é boa. Um conjunto pequeno de dados para reproduzir o problema é ok, mas se precisa de muita coisa o problema é específico demais. Esse é outro problema. E vale para quando os dados estão na pergunta mas só com eles que a questão se estabelece.

Claro que alguém pode argumentar de forma diferente por alguma razão, mas só nesse último ponto, o primeiro é incontestavelmente um problema.

A edição pode ser rejeitada, mas potencialmente não resolve o problema. E isso pode ser caracterizado como vandalismo, pode sinalizar para a moderação tomar providências. Claro que tem caso que precisa tirar porque o conteúdo é sigiloso, mas novamente cai no problema que nunca deveria ter colocado aquilo ali.

A própria pergunta acima já trata bem do problema, está corretíssimo.

Não esqueça de acompanhar os comentários que complementa o assunto.

Infelizmente algumas pessoas nunca vão entender o que é o SO. Ou não vão ligar para isso. Até pessoas experientes em programação acham que é um mural de *helpdesk*. É como programar e não saber o que é uma variável (muita gente com anos na área não sabe, ela usa assim mesmo).

Comment: Maniero, apenas aproveitando (não sei se devo criar outra pergunta), estava vendo [outras sugestões de edição do usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/501231/revisions) ([lista completa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/148342/user55546?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)) e vi que ele remove até os dados "escritos" (sem link externos). Essas edições também deveriam ser rejeitadas, certo? Isso me parece uma tentativa de _helpdesk_, onde com frequência ele faz a pergunta de maneira (quase) correta e depois remove os dados...

Comment: Sim, quase todas perguntas de R são ruins, tudo helpdesk específico, raro algo que ensine as pessoas fazerem. R é um enorme problema para o site. O grupo usa como mural de helpdesk.

Comment: Mesmo que "não devesse ter postado", não pode remover arbitrariamente, pois ao postar conteúdo, este passa a ter a licença do site. Óbvio que em conflito de normas, problema legal, ou até engano aí sim (mas não aparenta o caso, foi uma série extensa no tempo). Mas precisa fornecer elementos comprobatórios para análise e eventual retirada. Edições em massa para remoção de conteudo, se caracterizado vandalismo (o próprio sistema avisa) podem gerar até suspensão. A licença do site, que todo mundo concorda ao postar qualquer coisa é muito clara nesse sentido e é requisito para participar do site.