# Alguém pode me explicar o comportamento misterioso "comunidade" x "gerência"?

Tags: debate

---

**Edit: em 2019-01-08 o post 349 mencionado foi desbloqueado e fechado como fora de escopo.**
O assunto está resolvido e esta postagem do meta foi mantida apenas como parte da história do site.

---

Acabei de votar para fechar uma questão, e ao olhar as edições me deparei com isso:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/349/revisions

Já havia sido fechada e aberta, e ao procurar pelo meta, só achei referência a uma discussão sobre o assunto no **[link do comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/819/como-podemos-lidar-com-as-listas)** do @bigown bem no fim da lista, mas que não se trata diretamente da questão do fechamento.

Mais estranho ainda achei isso estar acontecendo sem ninguém dos moderadores envolvidos ter mencionado isso no Meta, já que contraria diretamente a vontade da comunidade.

Alguém pode me contar qual é a idéia afinal de contas? Grato.

**In english**

Just voted to close a question, and saw this on the edit history:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/349/revisions

It was closed and reopened twice. Didn't find any specifics on the reopening on the local meta, only some side discussion linked by @bigown at the end of the comments list.

What seems strange to me is, no one of the two mods involved give any feedback about the reopening on Meta. Probably it should happened, since it is against the community will (twice).

Can someone tell me what is the intention behind this?

> No fim achei melhor levar pra cá o assunto: [Strange behaviour, community x moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220791/strange-behaviour-community-x-moderation)

Comment: Diretamente relacionado: [Como podemos lidar com as listas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/819/como-podemos-lidar-com-as-listas). Parece haver um embate entre a vontade da comunidade e a da SE. A coisa não está muito clara.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal grato pela referência, este é o link que foi mencionado pelo bigown, que me referi. Só perguntei em separado pois lá não fica claro o que está acontecendo. Fez bem em postar o link aqui também, grato. Vou linkar na pergunta também.

Comment: Não é de hoje que [eu também quero saber](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/522/aqui-um-stack-overflow-qual) qual é a ideia, mas não tive respostas. Espero que haja um resposta oficial aqui.

Comment: Espero que finalmente tenha um posicionamento oficial. Depois de tantas coisas que nós postamos, nunca recebemos feedback se estávamos no caminho certo ou não, agora chegou no ponto em que não dá mais para ficar só aguardando para ver o que acontece. Eu acho que a "gerência" precisa deixar claro o quanto vamos poder decidir o que queremos e quanto vamos ter que seguir o que eles determinam. Não importa o que, mas precisamos ter isso claro.

Comment: Fechar esta pergunta como duplicata foi a cereja no bolo :)

Comment: Bom, não é duplicata. Estou discutindo o comportamento ditatorial aqui, e não a questão.

Comment: I realize the intent is a bit different here, Bacco, but the focal point is the same: what should happen to a specific question. It would be best to keep all of this discussion in one place.

Comment: Hope you and others are right, as I hope for pt.SO success. However, I sill have the same opinion as before.