# Onde podemos fazer perguntas, através do SO, que possam ser relacionadas a opinião particular de cada um ou envolver links de indicação?

Tags: suporte, perguntas

A questão é exatamente esta. Onde podemos fazer perguntas, através do SO, que possam ser relacionadas a opinião particular de cada um ou envolver links de indicação?

Exemplo, e se eu quiser saber sobre indicação de materiais para estudo, como um tutorial, de ferramentas ou uma linguagem que estou a começar a aprender/usar?

A preocupação principal é que ela tenha uma boa visualização como as peguntas na lista de perguntas do SO.

Ou definitivamente aqui não é o lugar para isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No momento, não há lugar para isso, que eu saiba. Entretanto, abriu recentemente (beta público, assim como o SOpt) um novo site na rede SE - [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (em inglês) - que *talvez* sirva para alguns tipos de indicação (software) mas creio que não para outros (materiais de estudo).

O [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) pode ser usado para pedidos de ajuda mais personalizados, já que ele é bem mais relaxado nas regras do que o site principal (não é "vale-tudo" entretanto). Ultimamente ele anda meio parado, mas no geral você encontra pessoas dispostas a ajudar. Não tem tanta visibilidade quanto o site principal, mas já é alguma coisa...

Por fim, há as wikis de tags. Em outras discussões (por exemplo [essa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/986/215)) foi argumentado que o melhor lugar para esse tipo de informação - material de referência, tutoriais, livros, etc - seriam as wikis de tags... o problema é que ninguém nunca lê elas! Os iniciantes não sabem que elas existem, e os que sabem não têm muito interesse por elas (talvez no máximo para escrever um bom fragmento explicando o uso da tag). E como não é responsabilidade de ninguém em particular mantê-las - nem se ganha reputação ou qualquer outra coisa por isso (exceto pelos `+2` pela edição) - elas acabam meio que abandonadas... Ainda não há solução para esse problema.

Que eu saiba, é isso. Nota: na mesma discussão mencionada anteriormente, [sugeri uma maneira de fazer as perguntas de recomendação funcionarem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/841/215), mas isso nunca foi testado na prática - nem sei como a comunidade reagiria a essa prática, provavelmente fechando como "principalmente baseada em opiniões".

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com é para mim uma ótima idéia. Tomara que dê certo! Obrigado pela resposta, já andei dando uma olhada em algumas wikis, a do C# por exemplo e me empolguei em obter um livro sobre C# a fundo, mas o link passado está com o estoque esgotado (rs). Bom, ainda não procurei em outros lugares, mas ainda me interesso pelo livro. Li sua resposta na discussão que passou e, *community wiki*? Ainda tem muita coisa no SO que não conheço. Ok, uma coisa de cada vez. Obrigado!

Comment: Enfim, continuar torcendo para a comunidade do SO crescer mais e logo ter um chat mais movimentado. Seria muito bom poder contar sempre e continuar centralizando minhas questões aqui.

Comment: Só para constar, é o **Profissional C# e a Plataforma .NET 4** que está indisponível/esgotado.