# Pergunta sobre fontes de estudo e resposta propaganda

Tags: debate

Todos somos cientes de que não é permitido assuntos não relacionados a programação.
Todavia, temos esse tópico:

[Referências para aprendizado de programação web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43105/refer%C3%AAncias-para-aprendizado-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-web)

Não deveria ser fechado?

Como exemplo, é como permitir tópicos que perguntam sobre referências para serviços de hospedagem.

Aproveitando o ensejo, a resposta do usuário "gustavox", é aparentemente spam/propaganda. Acho que não tem problema nisso. O problema está no foco da resposta.
É uma resposta muito pobre, desfocada do contexto da pergunta e focada 100% no serviço oferecido que coincidentemente tem o mesmo nome "gustavo". 
Não quero dizer que estou fazendo acusação, porém, é bastante suspeito segundo as circunstâncias e evidências.

Ok, entendo que a recomendação é negativar.
Porém, mesmo negativando, é permitido manter esse tipo de resposta, principalmente devido ao teor?

Comment: Acredito que só não está fechada por ter sido reaberta pelo Gabe (e eu ainda li errado achando que a proteção do Gabe era contra fechamento...). Veja o histórico http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/43105/revisions. Quanto à questão da propaganda, entendo que é culpa da pergunta ruim. Acho perfeitamente compatível a resposta dada com o que pode se esperar de pergunta que pede recomendação. Afinal, se o site for do Zé Carlos, da Maria Bonita, ou do próprio Gustavo, não imagino que faça qualquer diferença. Quanto à qualidade, aí sim o -1 ou +1 vai bem, de acordo com a opinião do votante.

Comment: Disse bem @Bacco "é culpa da pergunta ruim". As famosas listas impostas pela SE.

Answer (score 5):

Nossa, eu já tava saindo, mas como [tive uma pergunta suspensa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59154/onde-declarar-as-vari%C3%A1veis), resolvi antes passar por aqui pra ver se tinha alguma discussão a este respeito, e eis que sou surpreendido com este tópico.

Em primeiro lugar, é bastante óbvio que não sou o Gustavo Guananbara (LOL). Eu comecei a aprender desenvolvimento pra web pelo CursoemVídeo faz alguns meses, ao mesmo tempo em que estou tentando desenvolver um site jurídico...

Em segundo lugar, não é span nem propaganda não, é pagação de pau mesmo! Desafio qualquer um aqui a ir lá, assistir alguns capítulos, e depois mostrar algum curso PRÓXIMO a este em qualidade (gratuito e para iniciantes). Sou extremamente grato ao CursoemVídeo, porque está me proporcionando realizar um grande sonho (o SOpt também tem ajudado muito), e a ênfase na resposta foi tanto por gratidão, quanto por ter a certeza absoluta de que ainda será útil pra muita gente (se não apagarem né!).

Em terceiro lugar, a pergunta foi inclusive protegida, o que indica (pelo menos indicou pra mim) que é importante ter um local com as principais referências sendo atualizado, e não tinha o CursoemVídeo, que, digo e repito, é o melhor para iniciantes disparado.

PS: Editei o meu perfil pra ficar bem claro. [Este](http://gustavoborceda.jusbrasil.com.br/) sou eu. :)

Answer (score 5):

Considerando os esclarecimentos do autor da resposta, só resta o problema da pergunta. [O tratamento dado a ela pelos moderadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/43105/revisions) é uma experiência relacionada ao debate em *[Como podemos lidar com as "listas"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/819/como-podemos-lidar-com-as-listas)*

Nessa discussão todos parecem concordar que não temos a melhor ferramenta do mundo para lidar com esse formato de pergunta (listas, e particularmente listas de recomendações). Isso nos deixa com as seguintes questões:

1. Quando a pergunta não pode ser reformulada para se adequar melhor ao formato do site, vale a pena mantê-la (e indiretamente incentivar similares) para evitar perder informação? Em outras palavras, ter algum conteúdo, ainda que não tão consistente, é melhor que nenhum?
2. Temos poucos exemplos de conteúdos bons em perguntas que pedem listas (especialmente de recomendações). Estamos impedindo os bons conteúdos de surgirem ao fechar essas perguntas?
3. Se deixarmos essas perguntas sistematicamente abertas, o que aumenta mais: o volume de bons conteúdos, ou de conteúdos ruins e ruído? E mesmo que haja mais conteúdo ruim, pouco é melhor que nada?
4. Vale a pena trancar para que só aceitem uma resposta ("a lista"), mesmo isso impedindo a pergunta de receber votos, e portanto perdendo uma medição importante de sua popularidade?
5. Se é para manter as perguntas abertas, quanta resistência da comunidade essa atitude atrai? Isso pode atrair novos membros para a comunidade (não me refiro a mais contas de usuário, mas sim a gente que participa frequentemente)? Pode afugentar membros? Qual dos riscos é melhor correr?
6. Como reformular a ferramenta para lidar melhor com esses casos? O que mudar? Quanto trabalho isso representa? O possível benefício vale o esforço?

São todas questões em aberto. Precisamos respondê-las juntos para podermos avançar nesse debate.

Comment: `+1`- Outro possível ponto nas questões que levantas-te é "Onde está a fronteira entre conteúdo wiki de uma tag, e o conteúdo que eventualmente tais perguntas possam gerar", pois grande parte do conteúdo [dessa pergunta específica](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43105/129) estaria a meu ver melhor na wiki de uma tag.

Comment: Concordo com o @Sergio. Olhei todas as perguntas que colocaste e todas me pareceram ter uma resposta óbvia: Não vejo nada de bom neste tipo de perguntas. Agora ter esse conteúdo na wiki da tag e referencia-lo quando preciso parece-me ser o ideal.