# Existe alguma área ou tag do stackoverflow para quando o usuário deseja indicações de livros ou semelhante?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Pergunto isso pois as vezes vejo pessoas perguntando:

"Indicações de livros de javascript"

"Por onde devo começar para aprender linguagem x"

E obviamente a maioria tem downvotes, já sabendo que isso seja fora de escopo, mas é compreensível que o ser humano quando não sabe algo vai atrás de pessoas experientes na área, então será que existe alguma forma de fazer perguntas do gênero no stackoverflow sem sair do escopo?

Comment: Se perguntar no chat quase de certeza que tem sempre boa recetividade.

Comment: Chat no stackoverflow?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms

Comment: O chat [Estouro de Pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) é a nossa sala oficial e é movimentada todos os dias - praticamente.

Comment: Com tamanha demanda, eu acho que tem que ter no site, mas precisa mudar alguns detalhes na ferramenta pra ser adequado. E a comunidade aceitar. Tem que ser algo curado, não Q&A.

Comment: @Maniero Mudanças na ferramenta incentivariam mudanças na comunidade, mas se houver gente disposta a manter listas de livros de diversos assuntos, dá pra quebrar o galho como quebraram no SO. Só que precisa manter de verdade, ter uma certa quantidade mínima de pessoas se dedicando a isso e ter pelo menos algumas listas básicas. Eu acho que nunca vão mexer na ferramenta pra isso... E também não vejo a comunidade se mobilizando pra algo assim neste momento. Vamos ver se provam que eu estou enganado :)

Comment: @bfavaretto até dá, desde que não seja perguntas e sim post no lugar de perguntas. Mas atualmente é o pior momento pq a comunidade está bem desmotivada. Imagina começar bem e aí ficar abandonado... Se tivessem um pouco mais de motivação, e a SE se mostrasse mais disposta a fazer alguma coia, poderia sair algo em vários sentidos.

Comment: Eu também concordo que seria interessante poderemos ter uma lista de livros para determinadas ferramentas, mas parece que no formato corrente não é possivel. Curiosamente já passei por alguns posts desse genero no SOen. [Este é um desses exemplos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Seria bom se alguém criasse mais um nicho do stack como "stackoverflow library" para que os membros podessem compartilhar conteúdo diversos voltados a programação, como tutoriais, mini livros de autoria própria, etc...

Comment: Existia algo parecido: [o Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation). Estava em fase beta, mas foi descontinuado. Talvez não foi bem recebido ou não teve a quantidade suficiente de membros ativos. Não sei se um "Library" seria aceito...

Comment: @Isac Esse post que você linkou é o grande exemplo toda vez que esse assunto é discutido na rede. Pensei exatamente nele quando falei em "quebrar o galho". Vou deixar como referência também o debate que tivemos aqui sobre esse assunto alguns anos atrás: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/819.

Comment: @bio O documentation foi descontinuado(tanto quanto sei) porque era muito complicado mante-lo atual e relevante face às contantes mudanças nas tecnologias, e para além disso, acabava muitas vezes a "competir" com a documentação oficial da linguagem, mas com exemplos nem sempre tão certos. Pessoalmente vejo que esses problemas poderiam surgir também num conteúdo de listas de livros, assim como discutido no post que o bfaretto linkou.

Comment: @Isac, sim! Parece que o StackOverflow não pode fugir muito do Q&A. A comunidade (ou talvez o staff) parece um pouco "engessada" nesse quesito. Há outros exemplos, o link realmente é interessante.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> E obviamente a maioria tem downvotes, **já sabendo que isso seja fora de escopo**

A resposta está na própria pergunta.

No Chat, no entanto, não tem problemas perguntar por isso. Lá a pergunta seria melhor recebida. O motivo é que o site principal tem por missão ser um repositório de conhecimento e solução de problemas, não de recomendações. Recomendações são muito temporais e rapidamente ficam obsoletas. Mas no chat se conversa sobre tudo, e embora eu não o frequente, pelo que vi a cortesia profissional é característica por lá também.

Comment: Obrigado, apesar de não saber da existência desse chat antes foi muito bom descobrir ele, pode me ser útil em ocasiões futuras. Como dito acima, existia o documentation, pena que foi descontinuado, parecia promissor.

Comment: Só lembrando, algumas tags também têm indicações de livros/tutoriais.