# Essa pergunta está no escopo?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, fechamento

A pergunta [Desenvolvendo um WebCrawler em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96007/215) está bem votada e possui uma resposta na mesma situação, mas estou incerto se devo ou não votar pra fechar:

1. Não está claro se é uma [pergunta de recomendação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/57/215) ou se o AP espera algo diferente das resposta;
2. Não está claro sequer o que se espera que recomende: uma ferramenta ou um tutorial?

   - A edição sugere que ele quer um passo-a-passo, mas a resposta recebida só indica ferramentas prontas.
3. Os critérios estão um tanto vagos, primeiro ele fala de obter valores de tags HTML no conteúdo buscado e salvar num BD, depois diz que é só para "obter somente textos de links especificos";
4. Por fim, o que está sendo pedido me parece amplo demais (lembrei logo do [quebra-cabeça numa resposta do Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/911/215)), pois envolve "crawlear", interpretar o HTML e salvar resultados num BD.

O que acham? A pergunta está boa como está, precisa ser melhorada, devia ser fechada? Poderia simplesmente votar pra fechar como "não clara", mas prefiro sugerir algo concreto pro AP fazer em vez de simplesmente dizer "está ruim, se vira"...

Comment: P.S. Ao escrever esta pergunta aqui no Meta reparei várias com nome semelhante: "Essa pergunta faz parte do escopo?" "Essa pergunta está no escopo do site?" "Está pergunta está dentro ou fora do escopo do site?" Seria o caso de dar uma limpada nelas?

Comment: Como assim "limpada"?

Comment: Sei lá, talvez dar um título mais descritivo, talvez mesclá-las... Não acho que seja possível mesclar, já que cada uma delas deve abordar questões suficientemente distintas. Só noto que quando uma pergunta individual é trazida aqui pro Meta na tag `pergunta-especifica`, acabamos com um monte de perguntas tipo "o que há de errado com essa pergunta?" "essa pergunta pode ser reaberta?" "essa pergunta é isso? essa pergunta é aquilo?" etc. Com o tempo, não sei onde isso vai dar... (no Meta.SO, esse tipo de pergunta fica assim mesmo?)

Comment: Acho que as preguntas sobre _perguntas específicas_ tem um prazo de validade menor que o normal, podendo servir para guiar aqueles que estavam presentes na discussão em como agir em situações similares, mas para efeito de pesquisas futuras fica impraticável usá-las. PS: Não sei como é no Meta.SO, é um caso a se olhar.

Comment: Do meu ponto de vista ele quer inspiração, algo para se basear, podendo ser tutorial ou framework, creio não haver nada de errado com ela. O que pode ocorrer é ter muitas respostas, de varias pessoa recomendando APIs e tutoriais.

Comment: Eu acho que a pergunta foge do escopo por 2 motivos simples. O primeiro é que ele quer algo "pronto", ou tutoriais em CODIGO. Acho que ele não irá conseguir que alguém faça um tutorial em forma de resposta, creio que ficará extenso, mas eu desconheço a webcrawler, então não posso dar certeza.
E o segundo é que se a pessoa sugerir tutoriais além de ser somente links, que podem se quebrar, as respostas irão conter opiniões do tipo: Esse tutorial é bom, ou esse não é. Isso acabaria deixando a resposta baseada em opiniões.

Comment: Não acho fora de escopo, mas acho ampla demais.

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta certamente tem problemas, mas não acredito que esteja fora do escopo:

- O(a) autor(a) explica o que precisa em um problema de programação em cada um dos passos. Portanto, não está ampla demais: sabemos exatamente o que ele(a) quer.
- Para mim, está claro que ele(a) quer que o crawler inicie a partir de um link específico e comece a pegar os demais links apenas dentro daquelas tags. Isso é natural de um crawler.

Se ele(a) tivesse pedido a recomendação de algo já pronto para estudo apenas no final da pergunta, meio que como um bônus, você não teria visto de uma forma diferente? Acho que o pessoal das respostas também teria e não teríamos tantas respostas focando apenas na parte da recomendação.

Acho que a pergunta está mal escrita, mas tem salvação.

Eu estou mais preocupado é com aquela tag web-service. Não faz o menor sentido.